# Um contexto delimitado só possui código do modelo de domínio?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, ddd

Lendo sobre contextos delimitados em DDD fiquei em dúvida se isso é uma ideia que se relaciona só com a camada de modelo de domínio ou se isso é uma ideia que envolve mais partes da aplicação. Vou explicar melhor.

Pelo que entendi, em DDD temos a ideia de subdomínio, que é basicamente uma forma de particionar o domínio em si, ou seja, um conceito do espaço do problema. Por outro lado, pelo que eu entendi, um contexto delimitado é uma parte delimitada do espaço da solução, ou seja, serve pra delimitar uma região de aplicabilidade de um certo modelo com sua linguagem ubíqua.

Acontece que eu vi um vídeo recentemente do Vaughn Vernon no qual ele compara contextos delimitados com soluções do Visual Studio pra ter uma analogia. Só que numa solução existe bem mais código do que só o código do modelo de domínio.

Dessa forma, o que realmente fica dentro de um contexto delimitado? É só código do modelo de domínio? Ou tem mais coisas? Eu estou pensando da seguinte maneira:

No modelo de domínio existem além das entidades, objetos de valor e agregados, repositórios, fábricas e serviços. Pensando no uso do DDD com OO, o que estaria la na verdade seriam interfaces. Pra cada interface (`IRepositorioProdutos` por exemplo) eu preciso de uma implementação, claramente em um projeto separado dos tipos de domínio. Essa implementação pode depender de infraestrutura (o repositório depende, por exemplo, do EF).

Nesse caso, dentro do contexto ficaria **tudo** isso: tipos de domínio, abstrações necessárias, implementações e a infraestrutura necessária? Ou ficaria só o modelo de domínio mesmo daquele contexto?

Answer (score 5):

Quando delimitamos um contexto, tomamos em conta o domínio e não a infraestrutura que vai atendê-lo.

Assim, a insfraestrutura não faz parte de um contexto delimitado.

Veja, um sistema pode atender regras de negócio bem complexas e ao mesmo tempo ter uma infraestrutura muito simples, e uma mesma infraestrutura poderia atender todo o sistema e não apenas um ou outro contexto delimitado; deste modo não faz sentido infra e contexto estarem encapsulados juntos.

## O que está contido em uma *solution* de um contexto delimitado?

Não conheço o vídeo mencionado, mas uma forma de organizar um sistema Domain-Driven "designed" no Visual Studio seria sim criar uma *solution* para cada contexto delimitado. Mas cada uma destas *solutions* não conteria a infraestrutura necessária mas apenas referências aos assemblies e configurações da infraestrutura, que seria utilizada durante depuração e testes.

> Dessa forma, o que realmente fica dentro de um contexto delimitado? É só código do modelo de domínio? Ou tem mais coisas?

A *solution* de um contexto delimitado conteria então todos os objetos de negócio daquele contexto, sendo que alguns destes objetos estariam lá em carne e osso (interface e implementação concreta) e alguns estariam apenas em interface no caso de a implementação ser provida pela infraestrutura. A infraestrutura aparece nesta *solution* apenas na forma de assemblies referenciados e arquivos de configuração.

Eventualmente a infraestrutura ou parte dela também é desenvolvida dentro do time, neste caso os seus fontes estariam organizados em suas próprias *solutions*.

> Pra cada interface (**IRepositorioProdutos** por exemplo) eu preciso de uma implementação, claramente em um projeto separado dos tipos de domínio. Essa implementação pode depender de infraestrutura (o repositório depende, por exemplo, do EF).

Nesta afirmação reside um risco. O **Entity Framework** pretende falar a linguagem do domínio; **a proposta é que venhamos a consumir o EF no nosso código de negócio e não no nosso código de infraestrutura**.

## Precisamos de repositório afinal?

Há quem defenda a extinção de repositórios quando se utiliza o EF. Veja:

```
var equipamentosEmOperacao = 
        (from eq in context.Equipamentos
        where eq.EmOperacao == true
        select eq).ToList();
```

Qual a vantagem de eu abstrair a busca acima para uma interface *IEquipamentosRepositorio.ObtemEquipamentosEmOperacao* e daí escrever este código em uma implementação concreta que será obtida por injeção de dependência e blá blá blá? Possivelmente nenhuma vantagem e então pode ser melhor dispensar esta complexidade inútil.

Mas nossas regras são complexas senão não estaríamos preocupados com DDD; de modo que não é um flag que determina se um equipamento está em operação mas sim uma combinação de fatores: a data de referência precisa estar compreendida pela data inicial e final da operação programada, o equipamento não pode estar marcado como inativo, a aferição do INMETRO não pode estar vencida e a data de referência também não pode corresponder a um período de manutenção.

Então eu pergunto: vou repetir uma query complexa cada vez que precisar dela ou abstraí-la para um repositório? Com certeza vou abstrair para um repositório, e além de evitar duplicidade de código eu ainda terei o benefício de agrupar em uma única interface todas* as regras de negócio contidas na obtenção da entidade.

<sub>*Todas as regras de negócio que fazem parte deste determinado contexto delimitado.</sub>

**Ou seja:** Utilizando-se EF com regras de negócio complexas, o que pode ser extinto são os DAOs e não os repositórios. Em DDD, repositório não é DAO - ele não está lá para abstrair o CRUD, ele está lá para abstrair regras de obtenção e persistência de entidades complexas, partindo do princípio de que se as entidades não fossem complexas você não precisaria de DDD.

## A implementação concreta do repositório pertence ao domínio ou à infraestrutura?

Os fatores que determinam se um equipamento está em operação são regras de negócio, são determinados pelo especialista em negócio, logo eles pertencem ao domínio.

Então, a implementação concreta de *IEquipamentosRepositorio.ObtemEquipamentosEmOperacao*, usando Entity Framework, certamente pertence à *solution* do respectivo contexto delimitado. Pertence ao domínio e não à infraestrutura. A implementação do EF em si é que pertence à infraestrutura, mas esta já está naturalmente abstraída do seu código de negócio.

## Conclusão

> Um contexto delimitado só possui código do modelo de domínio?

Contexto delimitado é um conceito que existe além do Visual Studio - ele é de conhecimento inclusive do especialista em negócio. Por outro lado, quando organizamos o código de um contexto delimitado no Visual Studio, é natural criar uma *solution* para cada contexto, e neste caso apenas o código de domínio reside nesta *solution*. A infraestrutura está disponível através de assemblies referenciados e arquivos de configuração para serem utilizados durante depuração e testes.

Outro ponto importante é que a implementação concreta de repositórios, principalmente ao se utilizar EF, pertence ao domínio e não à infraestrutura.