# Quando usar Entity Framework com Repository Pattern?

Tags: entity-framework, design-pattern

Ultimamente tenho vários exemplos de *Repository Pattern* *homemade* nas questões sobre *Entity Framework*.

Porém o *Entity Framework* já implementa um *Repository Pattern*, que no caso é o *Unit Of Work*.

Muitos destes repositórios, atuam como um falso repositório que encapsula o repositório verdade(DbContent) para executar operações básicas, como GetAll, Atualizar, Inserir, etc.

Desta forma, não consigo ver benefícios neste tipo de implementação, podendo até trazer uma complexibilidade maior ao projeto em si.

Seria *Repository Pattern* um novo *Hungarian Notation*, onde muitos programadores ainda colocam abreviações do *Type* como prefixo da variável em linguagens com OO, quando este tipo de notação deveria mencionar a natureza da variável como prefixo e é desnecessária em linguagens OO?

Talvez eu não esteja conseguindo ver fora da caixa, então gostaria de exemplos com *Repository Pattern* que agregem valor.

Comment: Esta resposta fala de situações onde repositórios agregam valor: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51439

Comment: O que é Hungarian Notation? kk

Comment: @Rod, sabe o habito de colocar uma abreviação do tipo do objeto no nome da variavel? tipo `var strNome = "Toby Mosque"`, isto é o que alguns entendem por Notação Hungara... enquanto que a intenção atual era usar uma abreviação do tipo do dado na variavel, como por exemplo um dado seguro `s` ou não seguro `u`, como no exemplo: `var sValue = 515; //endereço seguro em memoria` e `var uValue = 6874168416; //endereço não seguro`... Em todo caso este habito é desnecessário para linguagens modernas, sendo útil apenas para linguagens de mais baixo nível.

Comment: @TobyMosque entendi, nossa, nunca me passou na cabeça em usar isso kkkk nem do tempo do vb6 não usava isso hauhauha

Comment: @Rod, mas com certeza você já viu alguém utilizando, provavelmente sem entender o por que daquilo.

Comment: @TobyMosque verdade...vi até em procedure sql hauhauha

Comment: o sp_ como prefixo de `stored procedure` por si só já é polemico.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

## Nunca

Simples assim. Implementar um repositório em cima de outro não faz o menor sentido. Isto fica fácil de ver analisando como se comporta o `DbSet`.

`DbSet` implementa `IEnumerable` e `IQueryable` (porque `IQueryable` implementa `IEnumerable`). Ao chamar métodos de extensão que devolvem `IQueryable`, o retorno é um objeto que acumula filtros. Por exemplo:

```
var query = db.Entidades.Where(x => x.EntidadeId > 25);
```

Aqui não estou executando coisa alguma. Estou apenas obtendo um objeto que, na resolução dele para uma enumeração, me devolverá objetos cujo valor de `EntidadeId` seja maior que 25. Posso ir acumulando predicados sem executar o código. Suponha o objeto `query` do exemplo anterior, posso fazer o seguinte:

```
query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Nome);
```

Nas implementações que vejo por aí, todos os métodos resolvem o retorno para `IEnumerable`, o que força o banco de dados a executar a resolução da enumeração (portanto, o SQL), acumulando resultados supérfluos em memória e aumentando o tempo de execução da pesquisa porque o resultado é desnecessariamente maior.

Abaixo explico as grandes falácias de quem defende repositório em cima de Entity Framework, bem como dou exemplos do exposto acima para que a explicação fique mais clara.

### Falácia 1: *"É mais prático de usar."*

Não vejo praticidade alguma nisso:

```cs
    public IEnumerable<Model.Article> GetArticles()
    {
        return _context.Articles;
    }
```

O exemplo fala por si. `Articles` é um `DbContext`, que implementa `IQueryable` (que implementa `IEnumerable`). Ao retornar `IEnumerable`, estamos forçando a conversão de `IQueryable` em `IEnumerable`, ou seja, executando a consulta inteira (como um `TABLE SCAN`, aliás, porque não há predicados de filtro definidos).

Além de ser um encapsulamento inútil, força o banco a trabalhar errado, faz a aplicação trabalhar errado e acumula memória pra operações que não precisa.

### Falácia 2: *"A ideia é não repetir lógicas altamente complexas várias vezes, em prol do DRY"*

Se a lógica complexa é repetida várias vezes, a solução então é padronizar 100% do sistema (que possivelmente é 20% ou menos que é realmente complexo) ou só os 20% complexo?

Que tal *extensions* para construir a pesquisa?

```cs
public static class MinhaPesquisaComplexaExtensions 
{
    public static IQueryable<MinhaEntidade> MinhaCondicaoComplexa(this IQueryable<MinhaEntidade> conjunto)
    {
        return conjunto.Where(/* Coloque aqui a condição complexa */);
    }
}
```

Uso:

```cs
var retornoComplexo = context.Entidades.MinhaCondicaoComplexa().Where(/* Sim, posso filtrar mais */).ToList();
```

Lembrando que não preciso usar `.ToList()` até o momento em que preciso resolver a enumeração. Ou seja, a consulta pode ser executada apenas no último momento, tirando total vantagem do comportamento preguiçoso implementado no *framework*.

## Falácia 3: *"É mais fácil trocar o ORM."*

Esta eu gosto muito. O mais fácil é refatorar as declarações de contexto, por exemplo, esta de uma aplicação que usa um contexto Identity:

```cs
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

Por:

```cs
private IApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

`IApplicationDbContext` seria a extração da interface do seu contexto (que é um repositório) aí sim podemos implementar um repositório em cima desta nova interface, ou seja:

```cs
public class MeuContextoDapper: IApplicationDbContext
{ ... }
```

Aí você usa o repositório que quiser.

Obviamente, os `DbSet`s precisam ser reescritos. Não recomendo usar apenas `IDbSet` porque alguns métodos de extensão só existem em `DbSet`. Melhor extrair a interface de `DbSet` garantindo os métodos de extensão.

## Falácia 4: *"O EF encapsula a abstração do repositório e a infraestrutura, então é preciso uma camada extra pra separar a lógica de negócio da infraestrutura."*

Errado. [Veja que a implementação tecnológica é separada da abstração do repositório desde a versão 6](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6).

Além disso, se fosse desta forma, não seria possível, por exemplo, trocar a *connection factory*. Veja alguns exemplos:

## SQL Server

```cs
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

## SQL Server LocalDb

```cs
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

## MySQL

```cs
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

## Oracle

```cs
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

## Firebird

```cs
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbProviderServices, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

## PostgreSQL

```cs
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
  </providers>
<entityFramework>
```

## Falácia 5: *"Não usar repositório com Entity Framework causa alto acoplamento e fere os princípios do SOLID e da boa programação OO"*.

Vamos revisar o SOLID:

- **S** - *Single Responsibility Principle*, **Princípio da Responsabilidade Única**: Uma classe deve uma única responsabilidade, e não ser um canivete suíço com milhares de funções;
- **O** - *Open Closed Principle*, **Princípio do Aberto/Fechado**: Em herança, as classes derivadas devem evitar ter métodos e elementos peculiares quando públicos. Melhores alternativas são o poliformismo, o uso de interfaces (contratos) e extensões (*Extensions*, quando houver);
- **L** - *Liskov Substitution Principle*, **Princípio da Substituição de Liskov**: Se temos duas classes, pai e filha, então os objetos da classe pai, em um programa, podem ser substituídos pelos objetos da classe filha sem que seja necessário alterar as propriedades deste programa;
- **I** - *Interface Segregation Principle*, **Princípio da Segregação de Interface**: Uma interface não deve ser gorda, ou seja, os objetos que a implementam não devem precisar implementar uma porção de métodos que, em sua maioria, não serão usados;
- **D** - *Dependency Inversion Principle*, **Princípio da Inversão de Dependência**: Abstrações não devem depender de detalhes. Detalhes devem depender de abstrações, ou seja, se uma classe ou funcionalidade é usada em muitos lugares com diversas possibilidades de classes, ela deve ser substituída por um termo genérico ou uma interface.

Em resumo, essa afirmação não faz muito sentido.

Aqui deve-se notar que a implementação de um repositório em cima do Entity Framework fere, em primeiro lugar, o **Princípio da Segregação de Interface**, pois as operações CRUD são implementadas por métodos que já existem:

- Selecionar tudo: `ToList()`, `AsEnumerable()`;
- Selecionar um: `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()`, `SingleOrDefault()`;
- Qualquer outra seleção: `Where()` seguido de `ToList()` ou `AsEnumerable`;
- Inserir: `Add()`;
- Editar: `Entry(objeto).State = EntityState.Modified`;
- Excluir: `Remove()`.

**Sobre alto acoplamento**, o único acoplamento que existe é entre o contexto e suas classes de domínio, que **justamente** foram feitas para moldar o comportamento do contexto. Ou seja, ainda que se reduza o acoplamento usando interfaces, essa geração de interfaces é inútil porque *Models* só fazem sentido quando usados juntamente com o contexto.

**Sobre o princípio da substituição de Liskov**, uma simples extração de interface de `DbSet` mostra que podemos implementar um repositório da forma com que desejarmos sem prejuízo de funcionalidades. Há outros prejuízos como a perda da geração de SQL por métodos de extensão de filtragem, mas a implementação é possível. Há apenas uma ressalva aqui: a própria Microsoft não respeitou este princípio, pois `DbSet` possui uma implementação muito mais rica que `IDbSet` no quesito métodos.

**Sobre o Princípio do Aberto/Fechado**, o Entity Framework suporta herança e composição. Quase todos os métodos que interagem com `DbSet` e `DbContext` são extensões, então a substituição deles é muito simples, bastando extrair a interface e reescrever o método de pesquisa em banco.

**Sobre o Princípio da Responsabilidade Única**, `DbContext` é um observador de `DbSets`, e apenas isso, e `DbSet` é uma coleção de registros de uma determinada entidade com as 4 operações básicas de um banco de dados: selecionar, inserir, editar e excluir.

**Sobre o Princípio de Inversão de Dependência**, isto pode ser resolvido por injeção de dependência, mas isso apenas se o time de programação fizer muita questão, porque um `DbContext` deve existir apenas durante o ciclo de uma requisição e, portanto, instanciado com ela e eliminado com ela.

Concluindo, o Entity Framework não fere o SOLID, salvo a exceção que falei de `DbSet`. Não fere princípios de OO. Não causa alto acoplamento.

## Problemas Clássicos da Abordagem

Agora que falei das falácias, vou falar dos problemas que o uso de repositório traz.

### Paginação

A resposta abaixo resume.

[Paginação C# MVC Asp .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77209/pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-c-mvc-asp-net/77222#77222)

### Carga Antecipada (*Eager Load*)

A carga preguiçosa (*Lazy Load*) é definida por padrão no Entity Framework. O que acontece é que alguns desligam a carga preguiçosa pra definir a estratégia de carga no repositório:

```cs
public MeuContexto() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
{
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    OnContextCreated();
}
```

Não sei o sentido disso. O correto seria o programador dizer quando a carga antecipada será usada. Isso é feito através do [método de extensão `Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx) ou pelo [método nativo `Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696785(v=vs.113).aspx).

A grande diferença aqui é que `Include`, num contexto de objeto `IQueryable`, é pré-compilada pelo Linq para gerar uma sentença SQL com `JOIN`, e não simplesmente usar uma operação em memória.

### Problema do Contexto Destacado

Supondo uma aplicação que utilize repositório em cima de Entity Framework e tenha um código mais ou menos assim:

```cs
var entidadeDependente = EntidadesDependentesRepositorio.Selecionar(...);
var entidade = EntidadesRepositorio.Selecionar(...);

entidade.EntidadesDependentes.Add(entidadeDependente);
EntidadesRepositorio.Salvar(entidade);
```

O problema mais comum é:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

Chama-se **Problema do Contexto Destacado** porque dois objetos estão sendo observados por contextos diferentes, sendo que o correto é haver apenas um contexto de dados por requisição. Ou seja, o objeto `entidadeDependente` está em um outro contexto, destacado do contexto do objeto principal, `entidade`.

É apenas mais um exemplo do uso errado do Entity Framework, que atua como observador de objetos, monitorando suas modificações e as persistindo quando `SaveChanges()` é chamado.

[A seguinte pesquisa tem alguns resultados sobre este problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22contexto+destacado%22). [Há também esta pesquisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22An+entity+object+cannot+be+referenced+by+multiple+instances+of+IEntityChangeTracker.%22), em que o problema é tratado com outros nomes.

### Problema dos Objetos Conflitantes

É caracterizado pela seguinte mensagem:

> Attaching an entity of type 'ClasseTal' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Muito frequente em projetos que tentam implementar o DDD. Ocorre ao tentar anexar um objeto que já existe ao contexto. Um exemplo clássico de erro é:

```cs
var entry = contexto.Entry(objeto); // Isto já faz o contexto observar o objeto. 
contexto.Entidades.Attach(objeto); // O erro ocorre aqui.
```

Pode acontecer com o mesmo objeto (pedindo para o contexto observá-lo duas vezes) ou com objetos diferentes, quando possuem a mesma chave primária.

Comment: falando em `LazyLoadingEnabled`, eu tenho o pequeno vicio de setar o `this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false` e fazer um override do `SaveChanges()` `this.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges(); return base.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Bem perigoso isso, aliás. Melhor confiar no contexto e usar boas práticas. Evita um montão de problemas.

Comment: Já tive problemas de desempenho em versões anteriores do EF, por algum motivo ele estava chamando o `DetectChanges` ao acessar qual quer propriedade, desativando o `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` tive um grande considerável de desempenho.

Comment: Deve ser na versão 5. Só sinto esses problemas de desempenho trabalhando com milhares de registros, até porque o contexto do Entity Framework não foi feito pra trabalhar com alterações de milhares de registros a cada requisição.

Comment: Sim eu entendo, realmente era o caso, basicamente era um serviço que recebia arquivos de diferentes fontes com diferentes formatos, e tinha que normalizar os mesmos, e devido a alguns empecilhos não pude usar o BulkInsert, e como resultado acabei desenvolvendo este vicio, agora é procurar um tratamento.

Comment: Sendo por *bulk insert* não tem problema usar esta abordagem, incluindo a versão 6 até. Acredito que seu sistema tenha algum dispositivo de validação adicional. O problema é desligar o `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` sempre.

Comment: (1/2) Bacana a resposta. Você vê mais alguma opção além de usar *extension* que dê resultado semelhante? Eu ainda acho arriscado nos sistemas demasiado complexos com os quais eu tenho lidado repetir queries em vários lugares, pois as regras de como representar um estado da entidade mudam, e ao longo do desenvolvimento de uma solução nova podem mudar muito, e ter que alterar todos os consumidores não é produtivo. Interessante sua idéia de encapsular só os 20% necessário, mas 20% num sistema grande já é bastante coisa e um estado de entidade que hoje é descrito com apenas 1 atributo dela...

Comment: (2/2)...amanhã fica mais complexo a passa a ser necessário inclusive ler outras entidades para definir este estado. Então aquilo que não estava encapsulado em repositório porque era simples agora precisará ser encapsulado, e eu terei que fazer alterações em vários lugares do meu sistema. Enfim, na minha visão a sua resposta, embora interessante, ainda não resolve o problema de sistemas complexos e eu particularmente faz mais de 15 anos que não tenho o sossego de trabalhar em um sistema de baixa complexidade.(Não acho que a resp vale o -1 que acabou de receber. Eu não ia votar mas agora vou +1)

Comment: @Caffé A complexidade depende muito da postura da equipe em criticar a arquitetura. Outra forma de evitar repetição é usando *Helpers*. Já falei disso em algumas respostas, mas não é algo consensual de ser aceito.

Comment: @Caffé Sobre estados de entidades, o Entity Framework trabalha assim: com apenas um atributo. Trabalhar com mais do que isso é extrapolar o que ele se propõe. Obviamente ele não existe pra resolver todos os problemas, mas resolve graciosamente a maioria deles. Os demais sempre vão demandar uma solução com alguma alfaiataria. Na minha experiência de trabalho, utilizar o EF me retirou um grande esforço e me possibilitou pensar no que é importante, que é a produção humana do sistema.

Comment: Veja que eu não me refiro à complexidade de arquitetura ou tecnologia, mas sim de regras de negócio. Um domínio complexo sempre vai resultar numa modelagem complexa, que precisa ser desenhada com cuidado e refatorada extensivamente. Eu tenho visto que expressar uma regra em um nome de método em um repositório é vantajoso nestes domínios complexos. Por favor, veja nesta resposta um exemplo real (embora esteja longe de ser meu exemplo mais complexo) de estado de entidade que demanda a interpretação de um conjunto de atributos dela e de outras entidades: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51439

Comment: @Caffé Mas então, o mecanismo que o Entity Framework trabalha pra validar as relações se baseia em dois dispositivos: *Model* como `IValidatableObject` e as relações descritas entre as entidades por decoração de atributos e por propriedades de navegação. Expressar regras de negócio em um repositório cai no mesmo problema de fatoração do repositório em si que você mesmo comentou.

Comment: Veja que naquele exemplo eu não falo de validação mas sim de regra de obtenção de entidades ("traga os equipamentos que estão em operação" e o que define que um equipamento está em operação não é só 1 ou 2 atributos da entidade). Mas você falando em validação trouxe à tona outro benefício do repo, pois apesar de que a maioria das validações pertencem à própria entidade, há validações de negócio que a entidade não deveria conhecer e estas pertencem sim ao repositório; e, mais uma vez, quando as regras de validação externas à entidade mudarem, eu mudo só o repositório (um só lugar para alterar).

Comment: @Caffé Mas então: o repositório é o lugar para harmonizar entidades? Eu não acho. Acho que essas validações entre entidades precisam ser feitas por uma BL, camada de serviço ou, no caso do MVC, pelo *Controller*.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26981/discussion-between-caffe-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).

Comment: Validações entre entidades podem ser regras de negócios (geralmente são). Se estas regras estiverem no Controller e eu precisar delas em outro lugar, como durante um processo de negócio ou mesmo para expôr um serviço para um sistema externo, como fica? Replico as regras do Controller em outro lugar? Na minha visão nenhuma regra de negócio de um sitema com a mínima complexidade poderia residir no Controller. 100% das regras de negócio devem estar encapsuladas em algum lugar (muitas vezes chamamos este lugar de "camada de domínio").

Comment: O Mosh tem um video justamente explicando quando o Repository Pattern é melhor que o DbContext, começa no minuto 5:04 e compartilho abaixo:
https://youtu.be/rtXpYpZdOzM?t=5m4s

É questionado dois padrões:
1) Não minimiza duplicação de queries de lógica (Que dá para viver sem)
2) Não separa a aplicação de uma mudança de Framework (Por exemplo, se você quiser usar Dapper em algum método em específico por desempenho)

Comment: @mqueirozcorreia Esse é o maior papo furado da história. Você pode usar Dapper junto com o EF simplesmente usando `db.Database.Connection.Query()`, porque o Dapper é uma simples extensão de `IDbConnection`. Pra duplicação de *queries* de lógica, isto já está explicado na resposta quando eu falo sobre métodos de extensão em cima de `DbSet` em escopo estático (*Helper*). Não procede.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez sem o uso de repositórios(Infra.Data.Repositories) as operações com o banco de dados passaria para dentro de `Command` ou seria diretamente na camada de `Solution.Application.Services` adicionando a referência do E.F ? Sempre usei Repository Pattner e com esse post fiquei com essa dúvida, se eu não tenho essa "Camada" do Repository, para onde iria as operações no banco ?.. =)

Comment: @JcSaint Por que você precisa de camada de serviços? Você tem uma aplicação Windows Forms e MVC em que ambas compartilham a mesma lógica? Raríssimos casos justifica usar isso, mas te respondendo, sim, a referência ao EF iria na camada de serviço.

Comment: @Caffé eu sei que a pergunta é bem antiga e como o Cigano atualmente não participa tanto do SOP, você falou sobre buscar registros com regras complexas ou implementações de regras de negócio. No seu caso como você implementou isto? Usando um `Helper`?

Comment: Começar com nunca, é a pior coisa que você podia ter feito, pois não existe solução bala de prata para a computação. Outro ponto curioso é que você só falou de get, mas não falou alteração de dados. Ainda pior é deixa o contexto "aberto" para uso indevido. Seu caso so poderia ser aplicado em caso extremamente simples.

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro Defina "uso indevido". Defina casos em que essa aplicação é incorreta para alteração de dados.

Answer (score 18):

Existem realmente algumas pessoas que defendem usar diretamente o *Entity Framework* ao invés de usar um repositório. Eu vou expor aqui algumas motivações que eu acredito serem válidas para realmente usar repositórios.

Montar um repositório não te custa muito trabalho. Basicamente você cria uma interface com os métodos que você precisa pra realizar o gerenciamento do ciclo de vida das entidades e então codifica tudo na implementação da mesma, em outro projeto.

Algumas pessoas acreditam que se você tem uma aplicação inicialmente muito simples é um exagero usar repositórios, mas como o trabalho para implementar esse padrão é muito pouco, eu normalmente o utilizo.

Algumas vantagens, ao meu ver, quando usamos repositórios são:

### Flexibilidade na forma de lidar com a persistência

Ao usar um repositório você ganha uma flexibilidade na forma com que você lida com a persistência. O que quero dizer é o seguinte: para algumas de suas operações de persistência você pode usar o EF, por outras você pode usar ADO.NET e otimizar a query. Isso sem falar em questões de "carregar ou não entidades associadas". Você ainda pode querer usar junto com EF outras tecnologias como [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), ou etc. Um repositório permite deixar isso tudo em um só lugar e seguir o princípio DRY (*don't repeat yourself*).

### Utilização em serviço de domínio

Imagine que exista uma lógica de negócio que lida com mais de uma entidade e não faz parte naturalmente de nenhuma delas como método. Nesse caso, você normalmente constrói um serviço de domínio. Se você usa repositórios e tem uma interface que faz parte do domínio, seu serviço de domínio pode utilizar o repositório sem depender de tecnologia.

Se você usar o EF diretamente, a única forma de fazer isso seria você colocar chamadas do EF no seu domínio, o que o poluiria com tecnologia e detalhe de implementação.

### Facilidade na troca do ORM, se necessário

Finalmente, hoje você usa o EF, mas talvez amanhã por uma razão qualquer você possa precisar trocar. Talvez você troque pra NHibernate, ou talvez apareça algum outro ORM que seja melhor pra sua aplicação por alguma razão. Se você espalhou o código do EF por todo lado, você vai ter que mudar em muito lugar, se você tem um repositório vai mudar num lugar só.

Comment: Pontos interessantes, a questão da flexibilidade é interessante, o meu único drawback aqui, seria que o uso de ADO.NET para realizar otimizações, neste caso acredito que a chamada de Stored Procedures pelo ORM gere um transtorno bem menor caso seja necessário trocar o Banco de Dados. A questão do serviço dr domínio, prefiro não comentar por não ser do meu domínio. Quanto a mudança de ORM, acredito que isto só venha a ocorrer devido a uma decisão muito ruim na hora de escolher o ORM, acredito que uma mudança de DB por razões financeiras (ex: Oracle para Postgree) seja bem mais comum.

Comment: Legal a resposta.

Comment: Fiz um estudo ontem sobre o tema e so acrescentaria mais um beneficio:
Minimiza duplicações de lógicas de consultas(query). Entao ao inves de expor um IQueryable, se exporta metodos que fazem consultas com filtros.
Vi isso no canal do Mosh e fiz o post http://aplicacoesweb.blogspot.com.br/2017/03/padrao-de-repositorio-no-c.html resumindo o que foi passado

Answer (score 4):

Não existe uma resposta definitiva para esse assunto. Uns defendem que o EntityFramework é o próprio repositório, (como na resposta que foi marcada como correta) outros dizem que o Entity Framework não implementa um repositório como o deveria, como você pode ver nesse vídeo (está em inglês)
[Repository Pattern with C# and Entity Framework, Done Right](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtXpYpZdOzM)

Pessoalmente prefiro usar sempre o padrão Repository. Como exemplo prático, tenho um sistema que foi inicialmente desenvolvido usando ADO.NET com padrão Repository, futuramente pretendo trocar por Entity Framework e, como tudo está no repositório, fica muito mais fácil fazer essa alteração.

Poderia acontecer de eu ter desenvolvido diretamente com Entity Framework e querer trocar para ADO.NET por motivos de performance. Na dúvida eu prefiro ter toda a lógica separada em repositórios, mesmo utilizando ORMs.

Answer (score -2):

Bem, estamos em 2022. E até agora não vi nenhuma solução para a discussão!
Justamente porque não há resposta única. Cada caso será um caso. Já temos padrões em excesso os quais são implementados de forma subliminar nas diversas frameworks, porém, sempre o bom senso é que deve prevalecer. Tudo vai depender do negócio em questão, suas necessidades e a tecnologia vigente à época.

Temos sim que utilizar algo parecido com o padrão REPOSITORY e/ou SERVICE sempre que possível se tivemos necessidade de algum tipo de "independência" de implementação. Mas isso pode ser feito de forma a conviver junto a qualquer ecossistema tecnológico.

Em fim, não há resposta definitiva para isso, cada caso será um caso e a resposta nunca será única.