# Erro ao deletar usando Entity Framework 6 e repositório customizado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, repository

Estou usando o Entity framework para fazer o CRUD no banco de dados, mas tenho um erro ao tentar deletar algum item:

> "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the
>   ObjectStateManager."

Estou usando o padrão de repositório, *unit of work* e *viewModels*;

Minha classe de repositório:

```
public class Repositorio<TEntity> : IRepositorio<TEntity> where TEntity : class
   {
    private readonly ContextoManager _contextoManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContextoManager>() as ContextoManager;
    protected readonly V1Contexto Contexto;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    public Repositorio()
    {

        Contexto = _contextoManager.GetContexto();

        DbSet = Contexto.Set<TEntity>();
    }
```

O método excluir na classe de repositório:

```
 public virtual void Excluir(TEntity obj)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(obj);
    }
```

A classe de *unit of work*:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{

    private readonly V1Contexto _dbContexto;
    private readonly ContextoManager _contextoManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContextoManager>() as ContextoManager;
    private bool _disposed;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _dbContexto = _contextoManager.GetContexto();
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        _disposed = false;
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _dbContexto.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _dbContexto.Dispose();
            }
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Tenho uma camada de aplicação em que uso o *unit of work*:

```
public void Excluir(UsuarioViewModel usuarioViewModel)
    {
        BeginTransaction();
        var usuario = Mapper.Map<UsuarioViewModel, Usuario>(usuarioViewModel);
       _usuarioService.Excluir(usuario);
       Commit();
    }
```

O deletar na controller da camada de web:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
    {
        var usuarioViewModel = _usuarioAppService.ObterPorId(id);
        _usuarioAppService.Excluir(usuarioViewModel);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Já tentei usar o excluir na classe de repositório assim :

```
public virtual void Excluir(TEntity obj)
    {
        var entry = Contexto.Entry(obj);

        DbSet.Attach(obj);

        entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
```

e também:

```
public virtual void Excluir(TEntity obj)
    {
        var entry = Contexto.Entry(obj);

        DbSet.Attach(obj);

        entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;

        DbSet.Remove(obj);

    }
```

Mas aí retorna o erro:

> "Attaching an entity of type 'V1.Dominio.Entidades.Usuario' failed
>   because another entity of the same type already has the same primary
>   key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting
>   the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in
>   the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some
>   entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key
>   values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state
>   to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate."

Para fazer os testes, eu tava removendo os dados do banco assim, que removia todos:

```
public virtual void Excluir(TEntity obj)
    {
    DbSet.ToList().ForEach(del => DbSet.Remove(del));

    }
```

Comment: Também pensei isso, mas fiz alguns testes e acho que não é essa a causa do problema, por que ele encontra o objeto, só não consegue excluir... eu sou iniciante ainda, não entendo muito desse ObjectStateManager.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não consegui resolver esse erro, então eu resolvi mudar a forma de como deletar.

Fiz minha controller receber apenas o id em vez de o objeto:

```
  [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
    {    
        _usuarioAppService.Excluir(id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Ai na camada de aplicação, eu apenas passo o id para a camada de dominio:

```
public void Excluir(Guid id)
    {
        BeginTransaction();
        //var usuario = Mapper.Map<UsuarioViewModel, Usuario>(_usuarioService.Excluir(id));
       _usuarioService.Excluir(id);
       Commit();
    }
```

Que passa para o repositorio:

```
public void Excluir(Guid id)
    {
        _usuarioRepositorio.Excluir(id);
    }
```

e no repositorio o metodo excluir ficou assim:

```
 public virtual void Excluir(Guid id)
    {
       // Contexto.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        var obj = DbSet.Find(id);
        DbSet.Remove(obj);
    }
```

E ta funcionando 100%!

Comment: Não tinha imaginado que precisaria carregar o registro novamente para o seu caso. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Ambos estão errados, este:

```
public virtual void Excluir(TEntity obj)
{
    var entry = Contexto.Entry(obj);

    DbSet.Attach(obj);

    entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
}
```

e este:

```
public virtual void Excluir(TEntity obj)
{
    var entry = Contexto.Entry(obj);

    DbSet.Attach(obj);

    entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;

    DbSet.Remove(obj);
}
```

A função de `Attach` é anexar ao contexto um objeto que já foi carregado antes de outra forma. Isto:

```
var entry = Contexto.Entry(obj);
```

Não tem utilidade alguma. `Entry` apenas localiza o objeto no contexto. Se o objetivo é a exclusão, um simples comando como o abaixo já exclui:

```
Contexto.Set<TEntity>().Remove(obj);
```

Mas pelo primeiro erro, aparentemente há o risco de o objeto nunca ter sido carregado. então o jeito é usar `Entry` e marcar o objeto como excluído **apenas**, ou seja:

```
public virtual void Excluir(TEntity obj)
{
    // Contexto.Set<TEntity>().Remove(obj);
    Contexto.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Deleted;
}
```

Comment: Deste modo era como eu estava tentando fazer, pois eu tinha: `DbSet = Contexto.Set<TEntity>();` e depois         `public virtual void Excluir(TEntity obj)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(obj);
    }`   Mas retorna aquele erro...

Comment: @AlissonSaggiorato Editei a resposta. Acho que agora entendi.

Comment: Quando eu tento fazer desse jeito que você mostrou por ultimo, ele retorna o segundo erro... Eu fiz um outro projeto mais simples, sem usar injeção de dependência e viewmodels, ai funciona...