# Paginação C# MVC Asp .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou com problema de performance na paginação com Entity Framework e SQL SERVER, primeiro ela faz `getAll` para depois listar a paginação

```
var bdPergunta = new PerguntaRepositorioEF(contexto);
var pergunta = bdPergunta.GetAll().OrderByDescending(x => x.data).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 200);
return View(pergunta);
```

Porém tenho mais de 60 mil registros nesta tabela e este `getAll()` está demorando muito, como posso fazer esta paginação sem o `getAll()`?

No MySQL quando trabalhava com PHP eu utilizava o `Limit(x, y)` para paginar, mas agora estou com esta dificuldade.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A abordagem está **incorreta**. Usar um **repositório** no seu caso é **incorreto**. [Já expliquei isso algumas vezes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+entity+framework+reposit%C3%B3rio).

Se você quer usar corretamente o `PagedList`, abandone este tipo de abordagem:

```
var bdPergunta = new PerguntaRepositorioEF(contexto);
var pergunta = bdPergunta.GetAll().OrderByDescending(x => x.data).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 200);
```

Um dos motivos para **nunca** usar repositório com o Entity Framework é que isto:

```
var pergunta = bdPergunta.GetAll().OrderByDescending(x => x.data).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 200);
```

É diferente disto:

```
var pergunta = contexto.Perguntas.OrderByDescending(x => x.data).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 200);
```

A primeira faz um `FULL TABLE SCAN` no banco, trazendo os 60 mil registros. A segunda insere um `TOP 200` na *query* (é a mesma coisa do `LIMIT` do MySQL, só que pro SQL Server). Ou seja, você não traz os 60 mil registros: traz apenas os 200 primeiros em memória.

Abandone a abordagem de repositório que irá funcionar com rapidez.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [PagedList MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc). Vai te auxiliar bastante! Você pode fazer esse [passo a passo aqui](http://www.macoratti.net/13/10/mvc_pag1.htm), que vai te ensinar a usar.

Instalação, abra o Package Manager Console e instale através do comando NuGet:

```
Install-Package PagedList.Mvc
```

No seu *Controller*, você define quantos registros vão aparecer por pagina:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? pagina)
{
   var contexto = new CadastroEntities();
   var listaAlunos = contexto.Alunos.ToList();
   int paginaTamanho = 4;
   int paginaNumero = (pagina ?? 1);

   return View(listaAlunos.ToPagedList(paginaNumero, paginaTamanho));
}
```

e na *View*:

```
<div>
    Página @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
    de @Model.PageCount

    @if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Index", new { pagina = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink("< Anterior", "Index", new { pagina = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
    }
    else
    {
        @:<<
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @:< Anterior
    }

    @if (Model.HasNextPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Próxima >", "Index", new { pagina = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new { pagina = Model.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
    }
    else
    {
        @:Próxima >
        @Html.Raw(" ")
        @:>>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Já estou utilizando o Pagelist MVC, o problema é este carregamento geral de registros que ele faz antes de páginar.

Comment: Não vai funcionar não porque a resposta esteja incorreta, mas porque o autor da pergunta está usando um repositório para selecionar.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez o que é retornado para `var categoria` quando vc instancia `new CadastroEntities();`?

Comment: @tek6 Não entendi. Onde está `categoria`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Desculpa pelo erro! O correto seria `var contexto`.

Comment: @tek6 Se eu entendi o exemplo dele, retorna algo derivado de `DbContext`. Esta resposta tem uma explicação correta, mas não resolve o problema principal, que é um encapsulamento desnecessário de repositório dentro de repositório.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Obrigado! Estou lendo algumas [coisas suas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+entity+framework+reposit%C3%B3rio).