# ASP.NET MVC - Alternativa ao DDD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software

Vou começar a construir uma aplicação digamos que, inicialmente pequena, cerca de 5 CRUDs e apenas 1 Core (este sim um pouco mais complexo em termos de negócio), mas que o objetivo é que ela cresça com o passar do tempo, usando .NET Framework 4.5.1 e EntityFramework.

Estou acostumado a trabalhar com DDD para aplicações corporativas grandes. Mas neste meu caso preciso de algo mais rápido e ágil para desenvolvimento principalmente neste primeiro Release que é pequeno. Como vou desenvolver sozinho, usar o DDD é matar uma formiga com martelo do Thor. Vou perder muito tempo reescrevendo o mesmo código apenas para burocracias de arquiteutra enquanto o que realmente importa que é meu Core ficará parado esperando.

Gostaria de usar uma arquitetura semelhante ao DDD mas menos complexa. Ou seja, eu quero continuar seperarando a aplicação em Visualização, Negócio e DB mas sem a necessidade de tantas interfaces e camadas como é usado no DDD.

Que arquitetura eu poderia usar? Como implementa-la?

Comment: Acho que [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80696/20615) pode lhe ajudar um pouco.

Comment: Infelizmente não dá para responder isto com tão poucas informações. No máximo seria apenas uma opinião sem sentido.

Comment: Mas aqui não damos opiniões, porque elas não servem pra nada. Como já diria o outro: "opinião e c*, todo mundo tem". Pra te dar algo que seja útil para você e para outros, precisa ser algo que tenha um mínimo de fundamentação, mesmo que em parte tem um pouco de opinião. Fica difícil fundamentar algo sem conhecer o problema que não foi explicado. E não sei se dá para explicar tudo o que é necessário aqui. A pergunta é tão baseada em opiniões quanto é ampla. Só gostar de algo é um péssimo motivo para adotar algo. Eu odeio DDD, sei porque ele é ruim (ou bom em certos casos).

Comment: Existem milhões de possibilidades. A pergunta não diz nem o que quer direito. Mistura tido o que existe em desenvolvimento de software. E quer uma solução mágica. Eu até entendo que não saiba sobre o assunto ainda, mas a pergunta nem faz sentido, e quanto mais explica, mais ela fica sem sentido. Parece que está jogando todas as *buzzwords* e quer que as pessoas falem o que é bom para você. Mesmo  que diga que não é isso, é o que parece. Se não é, dê um jeito de mostrar melhor o que deseja. Seria bom você repensar o que pensa sobre desenvolvimento. Tá adotando a pior prática. Adotar s/ conhecer