# Entity Framework - Dicas de acesso a dados

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

Estou trabalhando em um projeto utilizando o EF6 com C#, em uma das minhas classes tenho que guardar um arquivo, exemplo abaixo:

```
   public partial class Arquivo
    {
        [Key]
        public int ArquivoID { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public byte[] ArquivoFisico { get; set; }
        public string TipoArquivo { get; set; }
     }
```

o meu problema é na propriedade `arquivofisico` quando consulto os dados de outras classes que estão vinculadas a esta não gostaria que carregasse a propriedade `arquivofisico`, pois posso ter arquivos de 5, 10 MB, a memória do meu servidor vai estourar se tiver muitas classes... quero acessar esta propriedade somente quando utilizar um *handler* genérico para fazer o download.
Tem alguma dica para fazer isso ou tenho que utilizar lazy loading mesmo?

Obrigado pela Ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tem alguma dica para fazer isso ou tenho que utilizar lazy loading mesmo?

Não materialize a coluna ao selecionar. Faça da seguinte forma:

```
var arquivos = db.Arquivos
                 .Where(...)
                 .Select(a => new { 
                                    a.ArquivoID, 
                                    a.Nome, 
                                    a.TipoArquivo })
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Interessante, mas esqueci de mencionar que estou utilizando um repositório genérico para buscar os dados ai creio que a coisa muda um pouco de figura... utilizo o metodo get conforme abaixo: IQueryable<TEntity> Get(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate);

Comment: Livre-se do seu repositório genérico. Ele não serve pra nada. [Veja mais aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696).