# Filtrar resultados em nível de banco Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho a seguinte dúvida sobre usar o Entity Framework.

Possuo uma classe abstrata para a classe que se comunica com a base. Visando a performance quero ao invés de trazer todos os registros de uma tabela para depois filtrar, quero filtra-las antes de trazer.

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbContext context;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public BaseRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return this.dbSet.AsQueryable();
    }
}

public class MovimentoTratamentoRepo : BaseRepository<MovimentoTratamento>
{
    public MovimentoTratamentoRepo() : base(new PegasusOdsContext()) { }

    public IQueryable<MovimentoTratamento> GetMovimentoTratamento()
    {
        return context.Set<MovimentoTratamento>(); 
    }
}
```

E então chama-lo assim:

```
GetMovimentoTratamento().Where(x=>x.nome == nome).ToList();
```

ou

```
GetAll().Where(x=>x.nome == nome).ToList();
```

Existe diferença entre os 2 métodos?
É a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Se for do seu interesse, leia esta pergunta. [Quando usar Entity Framework com Repository Pattern?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51536/18246)

Comment: Qual banco de dados você está usando.

Comment: @LuãGovindaMendesSouza Sql Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL Server Profiler**

É normal ter esse tipo de dúvida com EF ou qualquer outra ferramenta de ORM. Para facilitar a sua analise seria interessante utilizar o **SQL Profiler**. Essa ferramenta você consegue interceptar todas as queris que estão sendo enviadas para o banco.

- **O que é SQL Server Profiler**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181091(v=sql.120).aspx

- **Iniciar o SQL Server Profiler**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173799(v=sql.120).aspx

**Conceito de execução no EF**

O EF apenas irá executar a query após a execução do comando `ToList()`, segue link.

- **Entendendo o ciclo de execução no EF**

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/advanced-entity-framework-scenarios-for-an-mvc-web-application

**Enviando filtros para o repositório**

Para facilitar a execução de filtros você pode enviar uma `Func<T,bool>` para o seu repositório. Veja o código.

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbContext context;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public BaseRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return this.dbSet.AsQueryable();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(Func<TEntity, bool> filter)
    {
        return this.dbSet.AsQueryable().Where(filter).ToList();
    }
}

public class MovimentoTratamentoRepo : BaseRepository<MovimentoTratamento>
{
    public MovimentoTratamentoRepo() : base(new PegasusOdsContext()) { }

    public IQueryable<MovimentoTratamento> GetMovimentoTratamento()
    {
        return context.Set<MovimentoTratamento>(); 
    }

    public IEnumerable<MovimentoTratamento> GetMovimentoTratamento(Func<MovimentoTratamento, bool> filter)
    {
        return context.Set<MovimentoTratamento>()
                      .Where(filter)
                      .ToList(); 
    }
}
```