# Chave Primária sem Auto-Incremento para CPF em Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, async

O cenário é o seguinte: Tenho uma classe Funcionário. A `primary key` dela deve ser o CPF do funcionário que o usuário digitar.

O Problema: a `key` segue um auto incremento padrão, não indo conforme o CPF inserido.

> EX: Digitei funcionário CPF: 492.203.120-90 se for o primeiro;
>   Ao persistir o registro da tabela, a key será inserida com o valor 1.

Classe Funcionário:

```
public class Funcionario
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name="CPF: ")]
    [Range(0,long.MaxValue)]
    [Cpf(ErrorMessage = "Valor Inválido para CPF!")]
    public long  FUN_CPF { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite o nome do funcionário!")]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "O tamanho mínimo do nome são 5 caracteres.")]
    [StringLength(64, ErrorMessage = "O tamanho máximo são 64 caracteres.")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome: ")]
    public string FUN_NOME { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento: ")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    public DateTime FUN_DTNASCIMENTO { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cargo: ")]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "O tamanho mínimo do nome são 5 caracteres.")]
    [StringLength(64, ErrorMessage = "O tamanho máximo são 64 caracteres.")]
    public string FUN_CARGO { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data de Adminssão: ")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    public DateTime FUN_DTADMISSAO { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data de Demissão: ")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? FUN_DTDEMISSAO { get; set; }

    //Data pós demissão desativar funcionario
    [Display(Name = "Ativo: ")]
    public bool FUN_ATIVO { get; set; }

}
```

Metodologia para o CRUD é o seguinte :

```
  public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity>
{

    Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id);

    IQueryable<TEntity> SearchFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();

    Task EditAsync(TEntity entity);

    Task InsertAsync(TEntity entity);

    Task DeleteAsync(TEntity entity);

   // Task Dispose(TEntity entity);

}
```

A implementação:

```
   public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        DbSet = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public GenericRepository()
    {
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await DbSet.FindAsync(id);
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> SearchFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(predicate);
    }

    public async Task EditAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task InsertAsync(TEntity entity)
    {

        DbSet.Add(entity);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task DeleteAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ideia de usar o CPF como chave primária pode ser bem interessante dentro do seu sistema. Apenas decore sua chave com [`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) para que o sistema defina a chave primária, e não o banco de dados:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
[Display(Name="CPF: ")]
[Range(0,long.MaxValue)]
[Cpf(ErrorMessage = "Valor Inválido para CPF!")]
public long  FUN_CPF { get; set; }
```

Comment: Obrigado, sobre o seu comentario anterior, eu aprendi daquela maneira com um tutorial da MSDN...Caso tenha alguma documentação melhor de como implementar,  vou ficar muito grato.

Comment: Basta usar o contexto diretamente, sem essa camada adicional. [Aqui enumero uma série de motivos pra você não usar isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696).