# Objetos Entity FrameWork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Estou tendo uma duvida com Entity Framework

Eu tenho uma situação na qual desejo implementar uma estrutura no banco de dados de um plano de contas contábeis, exemplo: a conta ativo circulante ID 1.1 é pai da conta caixa 1.1.1, está a minha regra de negócio

Supondo a situação hipotética que eu ja tenha a conta pai AtivoCirculante salva no banco, e deseja salvar uma conta filha, exemplo conta caixa.

Criei estes dois métodos: um que salva uma nova conta no banco, e outro que consulta uma contapai no banco e retorna uma coleção IQueriable

```
        //Método para salvar uma nova conta

    public static void IncuirDB(Conta ObjConta, string IDContaPai)
    {
        Contexto Db = new Contexto();

        var ContaPai = Repositorio.Consultar(IDContaPai, "");
        var ContaPaiFirst = ContaPai.FirstOrDefault();

        ObjConta.ContaPai = ContaPaiFirst;

        Db.Conta.Add(ObjConta);

        Db.SaveChanges();

    }

    //Método para consultar uma conta
    public static IQueryable<Conta> Consultar(string _IDConta, string _Nome)
    {
        Contexto Db = new Contexto();

            var Consultar = from c in Db.Conta where c.Codigo == _IDConta select c;


            return Consultar;
    }
```

O Problema ocorre quando eu tento salvar o meu objeto conta, que tem uma propriedade do tipo contaPai que também é um objeto do tipo conta.
Esse objetoconta vem da camada de interface de usuário e apenas desejo incluir uma propriedade contapai nele, antes de salva-lo no banco.
No entanto não estou conseguindo, pois tenho tido o erro abaixo.

Detalhe do ERRO:
"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Conta'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Conta'. The duplicate key value is (1.1).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

NOTA: Estou certo de que a conta que estou tentando incluir não existe no banco.

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Cara, não é melhor vc colocar um IdContaPai no ObjConta não?

Answer (score 3):

Tiago, a minha primeira dica é quanto ao uso do `Contexto`, é interresante que você faça todas as suas operações dentro do mesmo `Contexto` e que o mesmo viva apenas para realizar o seu trabalho... afinal de conta o `DbContext` utiliza `UnitOfWork Pattern`.

então no lugar de:

```
public static void IncuirDB(Conta ObjConta, string IDContaPai)
{
    Contexto db = new Contexto();
    //efetuar consultas e pesistencia.
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

faça:

```
public static void IncuirDB(Conta ObjConta, string IDContaPai)
{
    using (var db = new Contexto())
    {
        //efetuar consultas e pesistencia.
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Segundo ponto, não reinvente a roda... para que um método `Consultar(id)`, quando o `DbSet` possui o `Find(id)`? Além do mais, você está criando um segundo `Contexto`, além disto violar o `UnitOfWork`, como está usando um Repositorio Estatico, você pode acabar com mais conexões em aberto do que gostaria (sem falar no consumo de memoria), afinal terá de esperar pela boa vontade do `Garbage Collector`.

```
public static void IncuirDB(Conta ObjConta, string IDContaPai)
{
    using (var db = new Contexto())
    {
        var ContaPai = db.Conta.Find(IDContaPai);
        ContaPai.ContasFilha.Add(ObjConta);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

e por fim, antes de continuar a usar um Repositorio com Entity Framework... leia esta resposta à uma pergunta minha: [Quando usar Entity Framework com Repository Pattern?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern#answer-80696)