# Padrão ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou aprendendo ASP.NET MVC e gostaria de aprender sobre padrões de projeto, tenho muita duvida em como montar minha Solution.

Gostaria de saber o padrão de nomes para as Solution, pastas, camadas, projetos, saber onde deve ficar o dbContext do Entity Framework, as propriedades devem ficar dentro da pasta model ou dentro de outro projeto como por exemplo projeto em 3 camas e etc. O ideal seria se alguém tivesse um "esqueleto" de Solution para que eu pudesse ver ou algum link com exemplo.

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: O melhor esqueleto é aquele que o próprio VS monta para você. Não existe um padrão para o nome das soluções/projetos. Muitas vezes há complicações demais e sem utilidades.

Comment: Obrigado pela informação.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não existe um "padrão" para a estrutura do projeto, a não ser o que a própria Microsoft monta para você, que é o mais recomendado.

Neste modelo base, você já possui tudo em seu devido lugar. Se criar um modelo com Identity (*Individual User Accounts*) irá ver que o `Context` fica na mesma pasta dos `Models`. Se a Microsoft fez assim, existe um motivo.

Ao olhar os tutoriais na internet, você sempre verá inúmeros tipos de estruturas, a mais comum é separar em três projetos:

- Models
- Repository
- UI

Dizem que assim é uma separação em três camadas, o que não é verdade. A estrutura de pastas não indica se o sistema possui três camadas ou não: é apenas uma forma de estruturar o projeto, o que nem sempre é bom.

Abaixo você pode ver o modelo de estrutura gerado pelo Visual Studio, no projeto 
[MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1), onde você poderá seguir o tutorial e ver como a Microsoft organizou esse projeto.

[image: Padrão MS]

No demais, pode variar de projeto para projeto, criando um projeto para seus `Models`, ara reutilização, um projeto para outras plataformas... existem outros modelos, como em tudo, mas nem sempre que existe algo, que será a melhor opção.

Existem alguns modelos que é necessário que você deveria saber, que são:

- Todo Controller deve terminar com a palavra Controller, ex: Perfil**Controller**
- Todo `Attribute` deve terminar com a palavra Attribute, ex: `CpfAttribute`
- PartialView deve começar com **_** antes do nome (não é obrigatório, mas é o padrão), ex: `_Menu`.
- Todo Contexto deve terminar com a palavra Context, (não é obrigatório, mas é o padrão) ex: PrincipalContext.
- A pasta Shared pode ser acessada por qualquer `View`, então coloque uma `PartialView` que será acessada por mais de um controller na pasta Shared, evitando assim a repetição da mesma.

> Neste modelo você ainda pode adicionar pastas para suas ViewModels, Helpers, Extensions, etc. Apenas tente não complicar o que não há necessidade de ser complicado.

Comment: Eu vi em alguns exemplos que foi criado um projeto a parte para os Models e a pasta Models do MVC(Projeto Principal) deixou de ser usada, existe problema em fazer isso?

Comment: Por exemplo a camada de models (Projeto a parte), Repository (Projeto a parte) pode ter qualquer nome? não existe um padrão para isso?

Comment: @MauricioFerraz Se você estiver usando o EntityFramework não há motivos para criar um projeto para repository. O EF já é um repository, como você pode ver [nesta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80696/20615). Eu diria que da forma que descreveu é mais um anti-padrão. Separar os models você pode, mas desde que haja motivos. Qual a razão de separar se não irá utilizar para outros projetos?

Comment: Não sei, apenas gostaria de fazer um projeto onde tenha um padrão onde qualquer programador consiga entender o projeto com clareza. E também vamos supor que hoje eu crie um projeto web, ai daqui um ano me pedem para criar um outro com WPF com a mesma base, eu gostaria de estar com um projeto bem pensado e elaborado para no futuro não sofrer com alterações estruturais que podiam ser evitadas se o projeto tivesse sido criado em um bom padrão.

Comment: Outra coisa que eu vi também é que um bom nome de projeto começa com NomeEmpresa.NomeProjeto.NomeCamada, eu achei que existisse um lugar, um documento especificando essas coisas.

Comment: @MauricioFerraz Quer uma forma melhor para um programador entender do que a que a própria Microsoft "ensina"? Então, se você for utilizar os Models em outro projeto, crie um projeto para ele e referencia apenas. Você pode criar um projeto "Core" onde contenha esses dados. Mas não há necessidade se não irá utilizar.

Comment: @MauricioFerraz Você pode fazer dessa forma se quiser, mas colocar o nome da empresa me parece uma redundância desnecessária, a não ser se realmente precisar separar (caso tenha mais de uma empresa, por exemplo).