# O tipo de entidade de cliente não faz parte do modelo para o contexto atual

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Eu estou tentando reproduzir esse exemplo de EntityFramework com padrão repositório, conforme segue o link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn630213.aspx

Porém está dando o erro descrito no título do tópico.

Eu irei postar os códigos.

A primeira é a classe BancoContexto.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Repositorio.Entidades;

namespace Repositorio.DAL.Contexto
{
    public class BancoContexto : DbContext
{
    public BancoContexto() : base("ConnDB") { }

}
}
```

A segunda é a interface IRepositorio.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Repositorio.DAL.Repositorios.Base
{
interface IRepositorio<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
    IQueryable<TEntity> Get(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate);
    TEntity Find(params object[] key);
    void Atualizar(TEntity obj);
    void SalvarTodos();
    void Adicionar(TEntity obj);
    void Excluir(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate);
}
}
```

A terceira é a classe Repositorio.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Repositorio.DAL.Contexto;

namespace Repositorio.DAL.Repositorios.Base
{
public abstract class Repositorio<TEntity> : IDisposable,
   IRepositorio<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    BancoContexto ctx = new BancoContexto();
    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return ctx.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> Get(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
    {
        return GetAll().Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
    }

    public TEntity Find(params object[] key)
    {
        return ctx.Set<TEntity>().Find(key);
    }

    public void Atualizar(TEntity obj)
    {
        ctx.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void SalvarTodos()
    {
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Adicionar(TEntity obj)
    {
        ctx.Set<TEntity>().Add(obj);
    }

    public void Excluir(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
    {
        ctx.Set<TEntity>()
            .Where(predicate).ToList()
            .ForEach(del => ctx.Set<TEntity>().Remove(del));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ctx.Dispose();
    }
}
}
```

A quarta é a classe ClienteRepositorio.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Repositorio.DAL.Repositorios.Base;
using Repositorio.Entidades;

namespace Repositorio.DAL.Repositorios
{
public class ClienteRepositorio : Repositorio<Cliente>
{
}
}
```

A quinta é a classe Cliente.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Repositorio.Entidades
{
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
}
}
```

A última é a classe de console, Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Repositorio.DAL.Repositorios;
using Repositorio.Entidades;

namespace Repositorio.Console
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Adicionar();
    }

    private static void Adicionar()
    {
        using (var repClientes = new ClienteRepositorio())
        {
            new List<Cliente>
            {
                new Cliente { Nome="Microsoft", Ativo=true, CNPJ="9394.4343/0001-55", 
                                Endereco="1, Microsoft One", Telefone="11574739494"},
                new Cliente { Nome="Google", Ativo=true, CNPJ="1234.9494/0001-33", 
                                Endereco="12, Santa Clara, CA", Telefone="1185858483"},
                new Cliente { Nome="Oracle", Ativo=true, CNPJ="9876.4433/0002-44", 
                                Endereco="54, Santa Monica", Telefone="4884848592"}
            }.ForEach(repClientes.Adicionar);

            repClientes.SalvarTodos();

            System.Console.WriteLine("Clientes adicionadas com sucesso.");

            System.Console.WriteLine("=======  clientes cadastrados ===========");
            foreach (var c in repClientes.GetAll())
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", c.ClienteID, c.Nome);
            }

            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Irei deixar o arquivo App.config da camada onde fica a classe de console:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnDB" connectionString="Data Source=joao\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=db_repositorio;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
 <providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>

 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Além de complicar **muito** o que é extremamente **simples** (implementar um segundo repositório ao invés de trabalhar diretamente com o EF), este tutorial está errado.

No contexto, falta adicionar o `DbSet` com o model `Cliente`.

```
namespace Repositorio.DAL.Contexto
{
    public class BancoContexto : DbContext 
    {
        public BancoContexto() : base("ConnDB") { }

        public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Explicando:

Este erro acontece, porque (como o próprio erro diz) o tipo de entidade não faz parte do modelo para o contexto que você tem no momento. Ao fazer isso

```
ctx.Set<TEntity>().Add(obj); //Ao executar o código, TEntity vai ser Cliente
```

o código está dizendo: "Hei contexto, vá no seus DbSets e procure o DbSet `Cliente`, depois adicione este objeto nele!". Como não existe nenhum DbSet declarado, o contexto reclama dizendo que "o tipo de entidade não faz parte do modelo para o contexto atual". ***=)***

---

[Aqui tem uma pergunta bem interessante sobre o uso de repository pattern com Entity Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51536/18246). Acho que seria de extrema importância você lê-la e tentar tirar suas próprias conclusões sobre o uso do mesmo.

Comment: Excelente! Funcionou... Muito obrigado. Eu percebi que você nomeou o DbSet Cliente como Clientes, certo? Isso está relacionado com a criação da tabela que ele gerou na Base de dados que estou utilizando? Se eu criar mais classes do tipo entidade e declara-las depois no DbSet assim como você fez com Cliente, elas também serão geradas? Eu li a pergunta e também a resposta que você me passou, ela é muito explicativa e esclarecedora por sinal, muito obrigado novamente.

Comment: Você disse que esse tutorial que me baseei está errado pelo fato de implementar um segundo repositório ao invés de trabalhar diretamente com o EF. Onde posso encontrar um tutorial correto, pois já procurei por vários, mas não obtive sucesso na busca. E desculpe pelo comentário longo, eu estou muito impressionado mesmo por isso.

Comment: Isso "mapeia" o seu model `Cliente` dentro do contexto. Todos os DbSets vãoo virar tabelas no banco de dados. Sim, se você criar mais classes e colocá-las lá, elas serão geradas também.

Comment: Veja [essa série de tutoriais no site oficial do ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started), eles são ótimos e simplórios. Aliás, eu não disse que abordagem usada é errada, afinal ela funciona. Só disse que ela complica demais o que é simples =)

Comment: Irei procurar com certeza! A minha última dúvida é se posso ir adicionando DbSets conforme a necessidade ou se recomendável eu adiciona-los apenas quando eles estiverem finalizados e não precisarem mais serem alterados.

Comment: Mude-os a vontade. Ambiente de desenvolvimento serve pra isso =)

Comment: Meu caro, muito obrigado mesmo, por tirar todas essas dúvidas.

Comment: É um prazer poder ajudar =)