# Classe genérica para CRUD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net

Tenho algumas funcionalidades de CRUD em comum no banco de dados, como `cadastrar`, `buscar um registro`, `buscar todos os registros` e `excluir`. Para isso, no momento estou implementando uma classe manager cada tabela do banco de dados para realizar as operações descritas.

Gostaria de saber como implementar uma única classe para realizar essas operações em comum.

Comment: Você pretende fazer as operações "na mão" ou usando algum ORM?

Comment: Atualmente faço tudo pelo entity framework @jbueno

Comment: Tá, mas então você não precisa de nada disso. Veja bem, para salvar algo no banco de dados usando EF, você só precisa fazer **`contexto.Entidade.Add(objeto); contexto.SaveChanges()`**...

Comment: Tem como tentar explicar melhor o que você pretende fazer? Use algum pseudocódigo e tal

Comment: relacionado: [Quando usar Entity Framework com Repository Pattern?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80696/2363)

Answer (score 4):

Zack, como você usa MVC, aconselho a usar um `Controller` genérico.

Que poderia ser algo do tipo

```
public abstract class Controller<TEntidade> : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
    where TEntidade: class
{
    private Exercicio10Cep.Models.ApplicationDbContext db = new Exercicio10Cep.Models.ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: Paises
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await db.Set<TEntidade>().AsQueryable().ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: Paises/Details/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        TEntidade entidade = await db.Set<TEntidade>().FindAsync(id);
        if (entidade == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(entidade);
    }

    // GET: Paises/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Paises/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(TEntidade entidade)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Set<TEntidade>().Add(entidade);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(entidade);
    }

    // GET: Paises/Edit/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var entidade = await db.Set<TEntidade>().FindAsync(id);
        if (entidade == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(entidade);
    }

    // POST: Paises/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(TEntidade entidade)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry<TEntidade>(entidade).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(entidade);
    }

    // GET: Paises/Delete/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var entidade = await db.Paises.FindAsync(id);
        if (entidade == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(entidade);
    }

    // POST: Paises/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
    {
        var entidade = await db.Set<TEntidade>().FindAsync(id);
        db.Set<TEntidade>().Remove(entidade);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Para usar basta fazer:

```
public class PaisesController : Controller<Pais>
{

}

public class EstadosController : Controller<Estado>
{

}
```

Assim não sendo necessário escrever mais nenhum outro código do tipo Repositorio, Manager ou DDD, pois o MVC já é um padrão de projeto, não fazendo sentido escrever outro padrão de projeto em cima de um padrão de projeto, isso seria reinventar a roda.

Comment: Solução boa e sem balela +1