# EntityFramework 6: Dúvida ao Persistir um Relacionamento N para N

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Modelo:

```
public class Agenda
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Horario { set; get; }
    public string Local { set; get; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Exame> Exames { set; get; }
}

public class Exame
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Descricao { set; get; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Agenda> Agendas { set; get; }
}
```

Configurações das Entidades:

```
public class AgendaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Agenda>
{
    public AgendaMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Exames)
                .WithMany(x => x.Agendas)
                .Map(x => x.ToTable("AgendaExame"));
    }
}

public class ExameMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Exame>
{
    public ExameMap()
    {
    }
}
```

Método do Repositório:

```
public void Inserir(T obj)
{
    banco.Set<T>().Add(obj);
    banco.SaveChanges();
}
```

Não estou conseguindo achar uma solução para persistir a Agenda, pois o banco gerou as seguintes tabelas (como eu queria):

Agenda (Id, Horario, Local), Exame (Id, Descricao) e AgendaExame(Agenda_Id, Exame_Id)

E, com isso, devo pegar, da Agenda, as propriedades Id, Horario e Local e salvá-las na tabela Agenda. 
Depois devo pegar o Id de cada Exame e também o Id da Agenda e salvar na tabela AgendaExame.
Não sei nem para onde vou...

Alguma dica? Obrigado!

Comment: [Não use repositório com EF](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696).

Comment: Vishe, polêmico rsrs. Mas por quê?

Comment: É um lugar-comum, pelo menos entre programadores brasileiros, aceitar repositório sobre repositório como uma boa prática. Na resposta eu explico vários motivos pelos quais não é. Se houver alguma dúvida mais específica, é só perguntar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, nas suas classes você deve usar ICollection nas navigation properties. Com IEnumerable você não vai conseguir modificar.

No mapeamento:

```
public class AgendaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Agenda>
{
    public AgendaMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Exames).WithMany(x => x.Agendas).Map(x => 
        {
            x.MapLeftKey("Agenda_Id");
            x.MapRightKey("Exame_Id");
            x.ToTable("AgendaExame"));
        }
    }
}

public class ExameMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Exame>
{
    public ExameMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Agendas).WithMany(x => x.Exames).Map(x => 
        {
            x.MapLeftKey("Exame_Id");
            x.MapRightKey("Agenda_Id");
            x.ToTable("AgendaExame"));
        }
    }
}
```

Na hora de criar ou modificar não precisa se preocupar com a tabela AgendaExame. Ela só existe para a aplicação. Você só vai manipular as coleções.

Ou seja, se você adicionar um objeto assim:

```
var agenda = new Agenda()
{
    Horario = "12:00",
    Local = "São Paulo"
    new List<Exame>
    {
        Descricao = "alguma coisa"
    }
};
```

Ele já vai popular as três tabelas.

Ou para atualizar objetos já existentes:

```
var agendaJaExistente = this.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
var novoExame = new Exame()
{
    Descricao = "alguma coisa",
    Agendas.Add(agendaJaExistente);
};
```