# Relacionamento de duas tabelas MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Como posso fazer uma consulta Lambda, tenho duas tabelas Permissão e Funcionário, 
aonde ao informa o `email` do Funcionário, ele me traga as permissões do Funcionário, através do `email` que informei. Em `SQL` fica assim:

```
Select Funcionario.Email, Permissao.Nome'Nome permissao' 
from Funcionario, Permissao 
where Funcionario.PermissaoId = Permissao.PermissaoId
```

Uso Entity Framework, eu tenho esse método, e preciso retorna o nome da permissão do funcionário.

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username) {
    FuncionarioRepositorio _funcionarioRepositorio = new FuncionarioRepositorio(); 
    string sRoles = _funcionarioRepositorio.BuscarTodos().Where(c => c.Email == username).FirstOrDefault().ToString(); 
    string[] retorno = { sRoles }; return retorno; 
}
```

Comment: acho que sua pergunta precisa de mais detalhes para ser respondida, você está usando o que para fazer a consulta? Entity Framework? Poderia mostrar o código (csharp incluido) de uma consulta que você faz atualmente?

Comment: Desculpa não ter esclarecido mais, uso sim o Entity Framework, eu tenho esse método, e preciso retorna o nome da permissão do funcionário.

`public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
            FuncionarioRepositorio _funcionarioRepositorio = new FuncionarioRepositorio();            
            
            string sRoles = _funcionarioRepositorio.BuscarTodos().Where(c => c.Email == username).FirstOrDefault().ToString();            

            string[] retorno = { sRoles };
            return retorno;
      }`

Comment: Não sei se eu entendi direito. Esse método retorna o que deseja, mas está retornando dados a mais, é isso?

Comment: Poste também o método `_funcionarioRepositorio.BuscarTodos()`.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que você utiliza o Entity Framework e que você tenha as seguintes classes:

```
public class Permissao
{
    [Key]
    public int PermissaoId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Funcionario> Funcionarios { get; set; }
}

public class Funcionario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int PermissaoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PermissaoId")]
    public Permissao Permissao { get; set; }
}

public class Repositorio : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Permissao> Permissoes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Funcionario> Funcionarios { get; set; }
}
```

Você pode fazer a query da seguinte maneira:

```
using (var db = new Repositorio())
{
    Funcionario funcionario = db.Funcionarios
        .Include(p => p.Permissao)
        .Where(c => c.Email == "lucas@gmail.com")
        .FirstOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine(funcionario.Permissao.Name); // nome da permissão
}
```

Utilizei a versão Core do EF neste exemplo, o princípio permanece o mesmo para o Entity Framework 6.x.
Neste link tem outros exemplos e uma breve documentação de como carregar entidades relacionadas:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Notas:

a. É necessário oque você tenha um repositório com as duas entidades (DbSet).

b. Talvez seja necessário/mais adequado mapear o relacionamento das entidades através no método `DbContext.OnModelCreating`. Exemplo de como mapear entidades: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

c. A Query pode ficar significamente grande com a quantidade de campos das tabelas, então você pode incluir `.Select` ao final da expressão de busca se achar necessário.

Comment: EF7 não existe mais. Agora é o Entity Framework Core. Senti falta de um `public virtual ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }` em `Permissao`.