# Entity Framework 6: Erro de Select

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou tendo problemas com o Entity Framework 6 com Code First. As operações de "Select" dão erro e o EF6 não especifica a exceção, como mostrado abaixo:

Mensagem de Erro:

> Uma exceção foi acionada pelo destino de uma chamada.

Pilha de Exceção:

> ```
> em System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>    em System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>    em System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>    em System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslateColumnMap(Translator translator, Type elementType, ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace workspace, SpanIndex spanIndex, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Boolean valueLayer)
>    em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
>    em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>    em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
>    em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>    em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
>    em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>    em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>    em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>    em System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>    em System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>    em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
>    em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
>    em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>    em System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>    em System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindInStore(WrappedEntityKey key, String keyValuesParamName)
>    em System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
>    em System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
>    em ProjetoTeste.Infra.Data.Repositories.ClienteRepository.ObterCliente(Int32 id) na D:\Informática\Raphael\Projetos VS2015\ProjetoTeste\ProjetoTeste.Infra.Data\Repositories\ClienteRepository.cs:linha 43
>    em ProjetoTeste.Domain.Services.ClienteService.ObterCliente(Int32 id) na D:\Informática\Raphael\Projetos VS2015\ProjetoTeste\ProjetoTeste.Domain\Services\ClienteService.cs:linha 29
>    em ProjetoTeste.Application.Services.ClienteAppService.ObterCliente(Int32 id) na D:\Informática\Raphael\Projetos VS2015\ProjetoTeste\ProjetoTeste.Application\Services\ClienteAppService.cs:linha 30
>    em ProjetoTeste.Web.Controllers.ClienteController.Details(Int32 id) na D:\Informática\Raphael\Projetos VS2015\ProjetoTeste\ProjetoTeste.Web\Controllers\ClienteController.cs:linha 93
> ```

A operação de inserção ocorre normalmente:

```
public void Adicionar(Cliente cliente)
{
    _db.Set<Cliente>().Add(cliente);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Mas as operações abaixo são as que lançam a exceção:

```
public ICollection<Cliente> ObterTodos()
{
    return _db.Set<Cliente>().ToList();            
}

public Cliente ObterCliente(int id)
{
    return _db.Set<Cliente>().Find(id);
}
```

Não testei a operação de "Update", pois, para isso, é necessário obter a entidade previamente para ela ficar no contexto do EF para assim poder atualizá-la.

- O que, normalmente, pode ser isso?

Comment: O seu _db é o que?  não tem como fazer return _db.Cliente.ToList();

Comment: O "_db" é o context.

Comment: Em algum desses métodos você usa `try-catch`? `Repositories.ClienteRepository.ObterCliente`, `Domain.Services.ClienteService.ObterCliente`, `Application.Services.ClienteAppService.ObterCliente` ou `Controllers.ClienteController.Details`?

Comment: Eu uso o padrão repositório, e deixo os "try-catchs" no controller.

Comment: Sim, [retire o repositório que resolve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696).

Answer (score -2):

Cara seguinte tem nessa

```
public ICollection<Cliente> ObterTodos()
{
    return _db.Set<Cliente>().ToList();            
}
```

vc só esta entrando na classe sem fazer nenhuma consulta tenta assim

```
public ICollection<Cliente> ObterTodos()
{
    return _db.Set<Cliente>().OrderBy(p=> p.Id).ToList();            
}
```

essa expreção OrderBy(p=> p.Id) vai organizar em ordem crescente os resultados da sua classe Cliente que esta sendo representada por "p=" buscando pelo Id "p.Id"

é nessa outra função:

```
public Cliente ObterCliente(int id)
{
    return _db.Set<Cliente>().Find(id);
}
```

ficaria assim:

```
public Cliente ObterCliente(int id)
{
    return _db.Set<Cliente>().Find(p=> p.Id == Id);
}
```

Uma dica, procure por expressões Linq e expressões Lambda no C#.
Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Valeu Samuel, mas também deu o mesmo erro. Não tenho a mínima ideia do que pode ser, pois tenho um outro projeto que têm as mesmas configs e não têm nenhum problema. Vou ter que refazer todo o projeto, talvez dê certo.