# Simple Injector + UoW + DDD + Multiplos Contextos + Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ddd, ioc, simple-injector

Preciso saber como aplicar o IoC para dois contextos.

O cenário é o seguinte:

Tenho uma Camada chamada ***Core*** (aloca classes que posso reutilizar em outras camadas), onde coloquei a interface do IDbContext, IUnitOfWork e o UnitOfWork (dentre outra classes que não me estão dando problemas por enquanto).

Possuo dois contextos (**AdministrativoDbContext** e **FinanceiroDbContext**), separados em camadas diferentes com seus respectivos conjuntos de ***DbSet***, pois não tenho necessidade de expor algumas tabelas para contextos sem relação.

Unit of Work:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{

    private readonly IDbContext _dbContext;

    public UnitOfWork(IDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    //... restante da classe...

}
```

Logo isso, preciso implementar o IoC separado em seus respectivos contextos que também estão separados:

Camada de Infra do Administrativo:

```
public class AdministrativoBootstrap 
{
    public static void RegisterServices(Container container)
    {
        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IDbContext, AdministrativoDbContext>();
        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    }
}
```

Camada de Infra do Financeiro:

```
public class FinanceiroBootstrap 
{
    public static void RegisterServices(Container container)
    {
        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IDbContext, FinanceiroDbContext>();
        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    }
}
```

Após configurar, eu inicializo eles na Aplicação (MVC):

```
public class SimpleInjectorInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
          InitializeContainer(container);  
          container.Verify();
    }
}


private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
{
    AdministrativoBootstrap.RegisterServices(container);
    FinanceiroBootstrap.RegisterServices(container);
}
```

Desta forma dispara um erro de "relação ambígua", onde não pode haver duas classes implementando a mesma interface (IDbContext).

Utilizei essa opção dentro do inicializador:

```
container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;
```

Porém, quando vejo o objeto no Debug, ele não possui os DbSet do primeiro contexto (AdministrativoDbContexts), pois sobrescreveu, já que sequencialmente ele chama o trecho **FinanceiroBootstrap.RegisterServices(container);**.

Acredito que o problema seja em utilizar o mesmo Unit of Work, porém nesta [pergunta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/259894/should-i-have-separate-units-of-work-for-each-ef-bounded-context/260191) alguém responde que só pode haver um.

Quem puder me ajudar agradeço imensamente.

Comment: Está usando Entity Framework, né?

Comment: Isso, implementando o IDbContext dele.

Comment: Onde é que o seu `IUnitOfWork` está a ser usado? Note que `FinanceiroDbContext` já é um UnitOfWork. Voce deve ter cuidado com que voce está fazendo. [Veja aqui porque](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51536)

Comment: Como você pretende 'diferenciar' as múltiplas implementações da interface IDbContext? Por exemplo, supondo que eu tenha uma classe `Reposito`, com um construtor `Reposito(IDbContext db)`, qual contexto deve ser injetado? Isso depende do que?

Comment: Por que dois contextos?

Comment: No caso de uma aplicação que segue o DDD, é interessante manter um contexto para cada bounded context: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução para o seu problema seria criar uma interface e uma classe de UnitOfWork para cada contexto. Dessa forma, elimina o problema de relação ambígua. No caso do mapeamento das classes de contexto, você pode omitir a referência à interface IDbContext, o código ficaria assim:

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<AdministrativoDbContext>();
```

e

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<FinanceiroDbContext>();
```