# Será um problema com minha arquitetura?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, arquitetura-de-software, ddd

Sou desenvolvedor de software a um bom tempo, mas estou sempre buscando aprender “maneiras diferentes de se fazer as coisas”. Estou trabalhando atualmente num novo projeto e decidi basear a arquitetura em propostas sugeridas pela comunidade utilizando uma combinação de DDD, Entity Framework Code First e outras “coisitas” mais. Porém, na prática e devido a algumas particularidades de minhas regras de negócio, sinto um pouco de dificuldade em aplicar alguns conceitos. Eu agradeceria se vocês pudessem me ajudar nessas questões.

Esta é a estrutura resumida de minha solução. Todos os projetos aqui apresentados são do tipo Class Library:

- Core *– Contém funcionalidades básicas para todo o sistema tal como gerenciamento de recursos, globalização, etc.*
  *References:*
  *(...)*
- Domain *– Contém a definição das entidades e validações.*
  *References:*
  *Core*
  *(...)*
- Repository *– Responsável pela comunicação com a base de dados e mapeamento das entidades através de Fluent API.*
  *References:*
  *Core*
  *Domain*
  *Entity Framework 6*
  *(...)*
- Security *– Aplica as funcionalidades dos projetos acima para prover funcionalidades de segurança tal como autenticações e criptografias.*
  *References:*
  *Core*
  *Domain*
  *Repository*
  *Entity Framework 6*
  (...)

O projeto **Domain** contém uma classe chamada **User** definida pelo seguinte código (resumido):

```cs
namespace Domain.Entities
{
    public class User : EntityBase
    {
        private string _userCode;
        private string _userPassword;
        //outras variáveis....
        private int _customerId;

        [MaxLength(255), Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)] //Estou utilizando Data Annotations para facilitar os testes de integridade e definir restrições básicas ao modelo.
        public string UserCode
        {
            get { return _userCode; }
            set
            {
                ValidateValue(GetType(), nameof(UserCode), value); //O método ValidadeValue está definido na classe base EntityBase e tem o propósito de validar o valor a ser atribuído à propriedade.
                _userCode = value;
            }
        }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string UserPassword
        {
            get { return _userPassword; }
            set
            {
                ValidateValue(GetType(), nameof(UserPassword), value);
                _userPassword = value;
            }
        }

        //outras propriedades...

        public int CustomerId
        {
            get { return _customerId; }
            set
            {
                ValidateValue(GetType(), nameof(CustomerId), value);
                _customerId = value;
            }
        }

        //Propriedades de navegação para outras entidades relacionadas
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }

        //Construtores
        public User() { }

        public User(string userCode, string userName, string email, Address address = null, bool isAdministrator = false)
        {
            UserCode = userCode;
            UserPassword = "";
            //demais inicializações...
            CustomerId = 0;
        }

        //outros métodos...

        ///<summary>
        ///Retorna as regras da política de senha vigentes ao usuário por meio de seus papéis.
        ///</summary>
        public PasswordRules GetPasswordRules()
        {
            var rules = (from r in Memberships.Select(x => x.Role)
                    where r.RulesPrecedence > 0
                    orderby r.RulesPrecedence
                    select r.PasswordRules).FirstOrDefault();
            return rules;
        }
    }
}
```

Vou escrever aqui mais uma classe:

```cs
namespace Domain.Entities
{
    public class Membership : EntityBase
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

        public Membership() { }
    }
}
```

As questões que preciso resolver são:

1. A classe `User` expõe a propriedade `UserPassword` que, apesar de ter seu conteúdo criptografado, eu não gostaria de expô-la aos desenvolvedores finais, de forma que ela fosse uma propriedade interna. Porém, como fazer isto se no projeto **Repository** preciso ter acesso a esta propriedade para poder mapeá-la à respectiva coluna na tabela da base de dados?
2. Como pode ver, a classe `User` tem uma propriedade de navegação para a entidade `Membership`, num relacionamento um-pra-muitos. Um `Membership`, por sua vez, tem duas propriedades de navegação (uma para `User` e outra para `Role`), de modo que `Membership` faz um relacionamento muitos-pra-muitos entre `User` e `Role`. Através desses relacionamentos e propriedades, um usuário pode conhecer suas regras de política de senha (definidas em Role), como mostra o método `User.GetPasswordRules()`. Até aí, tudo bem. O problema é que, um determinado usuário não necessariamente vai poder ter acesso ao cadastro de papéis (Roles), da mesma forma que alguém que tem acesso ao cadastro de papéis não necessariamente terá para o de usuários. Por tanto, `Membership` não deveria expor suas propriedades de navegação. Mas se eu retiro as propriedades de navegação `User` e `Role` de `Membership`, como poderei suprir a funcionalidade do método `User.GetPasswordRules()` já que o projeto **Domain** não acessa banco de dados?

Existem algumas outras questões, mais acho que essas duas são as principais. Espero ter sido claro.
Obrigado por qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Olha essa resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80696/61561

Comment: Boa tarde, já pensou em utilizar ASP.NET Identity para cuidar da parte de autenticação e autorização na aplicação?

Comment: @RenanCarlos, este é realmente uma boa discussão (utilizar ou não Repository Patterns sobre o EF). Porém, não vi como as respostas deste post me ajudariam. Unificar a camada Domain com Repository não é uma possibilidade.

Comment: @FelipeDeguchi, A camada Security realiza autenticação e autorização baseado num modelo de negócio já existente e pode ser utilizada em qualquer plataforma (Windows, ASP.NET MVC, WebApi, Console, etc) não se limita a infra web.

Comment: Não creio que seria possível deixar a camada de conexão com banco de dados em uma WebAPI e utilizar DTO's (Data Transfer Object) para quando for necessário acessar dados de `User`, assim os desenvolvedores teriam acesso somente aos dados que você deseja que eles tenham. O mesmo serve para a segunda questão, dentro de uma DTO você teria as regras de Password sem expor o Membership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## RESOLVIDO!!

Consegui resolver minhas duas questões com uma única solução.

De acordo com a resposta obtida por uma outra postagem minha ([É possível restringir quem pode utilizar as classes públicas de um assembly?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175282/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-restringir-quem-pode-utilizar-as-classes-p%C3%BAblicas-de-um-assembly)) pude utilizar o atributo de assembly `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` estabelecendo uma relação de confiança entre **Domain** e **Repository** e atribuir o modificador `internal` aos membros e classes que eu queira ocultar dos demais assemblies.

Por tanto, minhas classes ficaram assim:

**`Domain.Entities.User`**

```cs
namespace Domain.Entities
{
    public class User : EntityBase
    {
        // código suprimido...

        [MaxLength(255)]
        internal string UserPassword  // modificado para internal
        {
            get { return _userPassword; }
            set
            {
                ValidateValue(GetType(), nameof(UserPassword), value);
                _userPassword = value;
            }
        }

        //outras propriedades...

        internal virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }   // modificado para internal
        public virtual ICollection<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }

        //Construtores
        internal User() { }    // modificado para internal para evitar a possibilidade de uma instância vazia.

        public User(string userCode, string userName, string email, Address address = null, bool isAdministrator = false)
        {
            UserPassword = "";
            //demais inicializações...
        }

        //outros métodos...
    }
}
```

**`Domain.Entities.Membership`**

```cs
namespace Domain.Entities
{
    public class Membership : EntityBase
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }

        internal virtual User User { get; set; }  // modificado para internal
        internal virtual Role Role { get; set; }  // modificado para internal

        internal Membership() { }
    }
}
```

Após definir as propriedades e construtores que quero proteger, incluí o atributo `InternalsVisibleToAttibute` para **Domain**:

**`Domain/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs`**

```cs
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Repository, PublicKey={chave pública de Repository}")]
```

Dessa forma, o projeto **Repository** obtém acesso aos membros internos de **Domain** como se estes fossem públicos possibilitando, assim, o mapeamento de cada propriedade pelo EF Fluent API sem problema algum.

---

### REFERÊNCIAS

1. [Classe InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Friend Assemblies (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/0tke9fxk(v=vs.110).aspx)