# É possível restringir quem pode utilizar as classes públicas de um assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

O cenário é o seguinte:

Tenho uma `AssemblyProtegido.dll` escrita em .NET que contém classes públicas. Eu gostaria que apenas assemblies específicos possam consumir tais classes.

**AssemplyProtegido.csproj**

```cs
public class ClasseProtegida
{
    public void AlgumMetodo() {...}
}
```

**Permitido.csproj**

```cs
using AssemblyProtegido;

class Classe1 {
    //OK
    private ClasseProtegida obj = new ClasseProtegida();
}
```

**Terceiro.csproj**

```cs
using AssemblyProtegido;

class Classe1 {
    //lançaria algum tipo de exceção ao tentar instanciar a classe.
    private ClasseProtegida obj = new ClasseProtegida();
}
```

Esse tipo de proteção é possível?

Grato.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível tornar os membros `internal` visíveis para um outro assembly específico usando o atributo [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Obviamente, você teria de mudar de `public` para `internal` as declarações que quiser compartilhar com o outro assembly específico.

Esse é um atributo de nível de assembly.

Exemplo de uso (cópia do site da MSDN):

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("NomeDoAssemblyAmigo, PublicKey=002400000480000094" + 
                              "0000000602000000240000525341310004000" +
                              "001000100bf8c25fcd44838d87e245ab35bf7" +
                              "3ba2615707feea295709559b3de903fb95a93" +
                              "3d2729967c3184a97d7b84c7547cd87e435b5" +
                              "6bdf8621bcb62b59c00c88bd83aa62c4fcdd4" +
                              "712da72eec2533dc00f8529c3a0bbb4103282" +
                              "f0d894d5f34e9f0103c473dce9f4b457a5dee" +
                              "fd8f920d8681ed6dfcb0a81e96bd9b176525a" +
                              "26e0b3")]
```

Você pode ignorar o parâmetro `PublicKey` pelo que me lembro,
mas isso pode constituir uma falha de segurança, pois outra pessoa
pode fazer um assembly com o nome especificado e usar os métodos.

Comment: Obrigado, mano.