# Puxar dados a um input ao digitar no campo

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Preciso de um script que, quando eu for digitando alguma palavra dentro de um campo, ele puxa todos os dados que estão relacionados a essa palavra, como um exemplo o Facebook, na barra de pesquisa, quando iremos digitar algo ele já vem trazendo tudo que é relacionado aquilo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Ou, aqui no próprio site do Stack Overflow tem na parte de inserirmos uma Tag, ele mostra tudo que tem relacionado as letras que foram digitadas no campo!

Só que no meu caso eu queria que ele puxasse os dados de uma tabela sozinha.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ da uma  olhada :), ja q o mvc ja tem jquery msm

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez é deste jeito mesmo, só que tem como implementar isso para puxar os dados de uma tabela no banco de dados ?

Comment: Sim, veja minha resposta. Se faltar alguma coisa, só falar por comentário.

Answer (score 2):

O que você está procurando se chama **Typeahead**.

Normalmente a solução não vem sozinha: acompanha outro *framework*, como o Bootstrap. Há algumas implementações do Typeahead para Bootstrap:

- [Bootstrap 3 Typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead)
- [Typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)

Ou usando apenas jQuery:

- [jQuery Typeahead](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/)

Dependendo da implementação que você escolher, pode haver um formato de Ajax diferente, normalmente pedindo JSON. Para estes casos, implemente uma *Action* em *Controller* que devolva JSON:

```
public JsonResult ActionQueTrabalhaComTypeAhead()
{
    var exemplo = new String[] { "1", "2", "3" };
    return Json(exemplo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Não sei o que você está usando para trazer informações do banco, mas vou supor que é o Entity Framework.

No caso, vamos supor que você está trazendo nomes de pessoas e seus respectivos Id's ([igual o primeiro exemplo daqui](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/), só que com pessoas ao invés de estados). Primeiro vamos montar a apresentação. Ela deve conter algo assim:

```
<div id="exemplo">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" id="typeaheadpessoas" placeholder="Nomes de Pessoas">
</div>
```

O Typeahead trabalha com um motor de predição chamado Bloodhound. Ele pode ser configurado assim:

```
        window.pessoas = new Bloodhound({
            identify: function (obj) { return obj.Descricao; },
            datumTokenizer: function (d) {
                return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.Descricao);
            },
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            prefetch: {
                ttl: 0,
                url: '@Url.Action("PreCargaTypeAhead", "Pessoas")'
            },
            remote: {
                url: '@Url.Action("ActionQueTrabalhaComTypeAhead", "Pessoas")',
                replace: function (url, uriEncodedQuery) {
                    return url + '?termo=' + uriEncodedQuery;
                }
            }
        });

        window.pessoas.initialize();
        window.typeahead_pessoas_data = {
            name: 'pessoas',
            displayKey: 'Descricao',
            source: window.pessoas,
            limit: 10,
            templates: {
                empty: [
                  '<div class="typeahead-empty-message">',
                    'Não encontrado',
                  '</div>'
                ].join('\n')
            }
        };

        window.typeahead_options = {
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 3
        };

        $('#typeaheadpessoas').typeahead(window.typeahead_options, typeahead_pessoas_data
        ).on('typeahead:selected', function (event, data) {
            // Faça alguma coisa aqui com data. Data é um json.
        });
```

Um exemplo de busca de dados:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<JsonResult> ActionQueTrabalhaComTypeAhead(String termo)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(termo)) return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        // Aqui faço a pesquisa ao banco de dados.
        // Pesquiso ou pelo nome da pessoa ou pelo seu CPF.
        var pessoas = await db.Pessoas.Where(r => r.Nome.Contains(termo) || r.Cpf.Contains(termo)).ToListAsync();

        return Json(pessoas.Select(p => new
        {
            PessoaId = p.PessoaId,
            Descricao = p.Nome + " - " + p.Cpf
        }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: você poderia ser um pouco mais especifico, entrei recentemente nesta area de programação e ainda estou meio perdido, tipo poderia me dar um exemplo de como vincular esse script ao banco

Comment: Pronto. Veja se precisa de mais alguma coisa.

Comment: Irei tentar implementar no meu sistema, mas mesmo assim, já agradeço a sua ajuda!

Comment: Você poderia me mostrar como que você fez na parte do seu service e repository ?

Comment: Service? Repository? **Não use isso!** Leia isto aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso ele não puxa do banco ao digitar e sim puxa todos os dados e monta o script necessário para o autocomplete, ou seja, fornece sugestões enquanto você digita no campo.

Usei php porque só sei php e asp para acessar o banco.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "USUARRIO", "SENHA", "DB");
$query = ("SELECT COLUNA FROM TABELA");
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $dados = $dados."\"".$row["pedido"]."\",";
  }
}
$dados = substr($dados,0,-1); //retira a ultima virgula
mysqli_close($con);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
  var availableTags = [<?php echo $dados?>];
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```