# Atualização de muitos-pra-muitos com o EF 6

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6

Meu problema é quando tento atualizar uma entidade que tem uma classe filho que por sua vez, tem outros filhos. A estrutura é essa:

```
public class Diagrama
{
    [Key]
    public int Numero_Diagrama { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Transicao> Transicoes { get; set; }
}

public class Transicao
{
    [Key]
    public int Numero_Transicao { get; set; }

    public int Numero_Diagrama { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Acao> Acoes { get; set; }
}

public class Acao
{
    [Key]
    public int Numero_Acao { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Transicao> Transicoes { get; set; }
}
```

> Diagrama para Transição (1-n)
>
> Transição para Ações (n-n)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transicao>()
    .HasMany(s => s.Acoes)
    .WithMany(c => c.Transicoes)
    .Map(cs =>
    {
         cs.MapLeftKey("Numero_Transicao");
         cs.MapRightKey("Numero_Acao");
         cs.ToTable("wrfTransicaoAcoes");
    });
```

Quando tento alterar o State do diagrama para Modified ele dá o erro:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Attaching an entity of type 'Acao' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.'

```
    public virtual void Atualizar(TEntity obj)
    {
        ValidaEntidade(obj);

        using (Contexto Db = new Contexto())
        {
            Db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Isso está ocorrendo porque tenho uma Ação em 2 transições diferentes. Mas só estou alterando o Diagrama.

Estrutura dos dados, que já estão no banco e carregadas na classe Diagrama:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu excluir a última linha da transição 49, tudo funciona, pois ela também faz referência a ação 4.

Alguém tem uma luz?

Comment: Qual o código completo da lógica manipulando as transições e ações?

Comment: Olá @CiganoMorrisonMendez, na verdade os registros já existem e já estão vinculados corretamente (não estou salvando a transição atualizando o diagrama, eu faço direto), o problema é quando tento atualizar uma propriedade qualquer do Diagrama.

Comment: Só pra esclarecer, as relações entre diagrama x transições x ações já vieram do banco prontas. Só estou alterando a descrição do diagrama. Não sei se é isso que queria saber

Comment: Esse `obj` é um `Diagrama`, certo?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Coloquei na pergunta mais algumas coisas, os dados com estão no banco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro quer dizer que você mandou para o contexto o mesmo objeto `Acao` duas vezes, sendo que no primeiro objeto não há alteração, e no segundo há alteração.

Se você está apenas alterando um objeto `Diagrama`, não tem porque mandar o objeto `Diagrama` com todos os registros agregados. Você manda apenas o objeto e é isso.

Isto sugere que você está usando repositório genérico em cima de Entity Framework, o que [já expliquei centenas de vezes que é errado usar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696):

```
public virtual void Atualizar(TEntity obj)
{
    ValidaEntidade(obj);

    using (Contexto Db = new Contexto())
    {
        Db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Além de errada, a prática não te permite desanexar da observação do contexto entidades que não estão sendo manipuladas (seu caso).

Não sei se você está usando ASP.NET MVC. A maneira fácil de resolver isso no ASP.NET MVC é no *Controller*, excluindo as propriedades do *binding*:

```
public ActionResult Editar([Bind(Exclude = "Transicoes")] Diagrama diagrama)
{ ... }
```

Se não está, o jeito simples de resolver é não definindo a propriedade de navegação `Transicoes`:

```
diagrama.Transicoes = null;
```

Desanexar todos os objetos de `Transicao` e `Acao` do contexto também resolve, mas a operação fica mais demorada porque o Entity Framework tenta salvar não apenas o objeto da classe `Diagrama`, mas todos os outros objetos agregados:

```
foreach (var transicao in diagrama.Transicoes)
{
    Db.Entry(transicao).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
```

Comment: Meu caso é WinForms. Setando **null** para as transações resolveu. Especializei o método atualizar     public override void Atualizar(Diagrama obj) e inclui essa linha. Não estou usando repositório genérico, só tenho uma classe base para os cadastros simples usarem. Não sei se é sobre isso que está falando. Só para constar, a segunda forma não resolve. Muito obrigado.

Comment: A segunda forma não resolve porque provavelmente outra lógica está reinserindo os objetos mais uma vez. Minha recomendação para Web Forms é a de criar e destruir contextos no *Code Behind* (igual você já está usando: `using (Contexto Db = new Contexto())`). Não precisa definir uma camada intermediária, a não ser que você precise repetir a lógica. Se precisar repetir, crie um *Helper* para cada regra de negócio que deve ser replicada, executando código sempre em escopo estático. Estou sempre aqui para ajudar ;)

Comment: Vlw Cigano, acho que estou no caminho certo então, pois é o que estou fazendo. Crio e destruo em cada requisição e só tenho uma Base para os CRUDs mais simples. Obrigado de novo.