# Unity e UnitOfWork

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Salve galera,

Criei um pequeno projeto para aplicar **IoC** utilizando o **Unity** da MS. Primeiramente sempre usei o conceito de **UnitOfWork** apenas instanciado ele em meus **controllers**, mas agora quero injetar eles.
Quando inicio a aplicação web ele lista corretamente as informações do banco, porem sempre que chamo o **SaveChanges** está dando o erro: **{"The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."}**

Não estou conseguindo achar o motivo disso, visto que o contexto está sendo injeto no UnitOfWork corretamente, se não ele nem conseguiria listar as informações do banco. Segue meu código.

**Unity Config**

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc;
using MyMoney.DAL.Repositories;
using MyMoney.DAL.UnitOfWork;
using MyMoney.Domain.Interfaces.Repositories;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyMoney.DAL.Unity
{
    public class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
        {
            var container = BuildUnityContainer();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
            return container;
        }
        private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            container.RegisterType(typeof(ITransaction), typeof(TransactionRepository));

            container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

            return container;
        }
    }
}
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
using System;
using MyMoney.DAL.Context;
using MyMoney.Domain.Interfaces.Repositories;

namespace MyMoney.DAL.UnitOfWork
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private MyMoneyContext _context;
        private ITransaction _transactionRepository;

        public UnitOfWork(MyMoneyContext context, ITransaction transactionRepository)
        {
            this._context = context;
            this._transactionRepository = transactionRepository;
        }

        public ITransaction TransactionRepository
        {
            get
            {
                return _transactionRepository;
            }
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _context.Dispose();
                }
            }

            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**Repositorio base**

```
using MyMoney.DAL.Context;
using MyMoney.Domain.Interfaces.Repositories;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyMoney.DAL.Repositories
{
    public abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IDisposable, IRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected MyMoneyContext db;

        public RepositoryBase(MyMoneyContext db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }

        public virtual void Add(TEntity obj, Guid userId)
        {
            db.Set<TEntity>().Add(obj);
        }

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    db.Dispose();
                }
            }

            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(Guid userId)
        {
            return db.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetById(int id, Guid userId)
        {
            return db.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        }

        public virtual void Remove(int id)
        {
            TEntity obj = db.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
            db.Set<TEntity>().Remove(obj);
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public virtual void Update(TEntity obj)
        {
            db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
```

**Repositório**

```
using MyMoney.DAL.Context;
using MyMoney.Domain.Entities;
using MyMoney.Domain.Interfaces.Repositories;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyMoney.DAL.Repositories
{
    public class TransactionRepository : RepositoryBase<Transaction>, ITransaction
    {
        public TransactionRepository(MyMoneyContext db) : base(db)
        {
        }

        public override IEnumerable<Transaction> GetAll(Guid userId)
        {
            return db.Transations.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToList();
        }

        public override void Add(Transaction transaction, Guid userId)
        {
            transaction.UserId = userId;
            db.Transations.Add(transaction);
        }

        public override Transaction GetById(int id, Guid userId)
        {
            return db.Transations.Where(x => x.UserId == userId && x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using AutoMapper;
using MyMoney.Domain.Entities;
using MyMoney.MVC.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Text;
using MyMoney.DAL.UnitOfWork;

namespace MyMoney.MVC.Controllers
{
    public class TransactionsController : Controller
    {
        readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        readonly Guid userId;

        public TransactionsController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            userId = new Guid(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }

        // GET: Transactions
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult TransactionList()
        {
            var tList = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Transaction>, IEnumerable<TransactionViewModel>>(_unitOfWork.TransactionRepository.GetAll(userId));

            return this.PartialView("TransactionList", tList.ToList());
        }

        public PartialViewResult EditCreateForm(int id = 0)
        {
            TransactionViewModel viewModel = null;

            if (id > 0)
            {
                var transaction = _unitOfWork.TransactionRepository.GetById(id, userId);
                viewModel = Mapper.Map<Transaction, TransactionViewModel>(transaction);
            }

            return this.PartialView("EditCreate", viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditCreate(TransactionViewModel viewModel)
        {
            try
            {
                if (viewModel.Id > 0)
                {
                    var transactionDomain = Mapper.Map<TransactionViewModel, Transaction>(viewModel);
                    _unitOfWork.TransactionRepository.Update(transactionDomain);
                    _unitOfWork.Save();

                    return Json(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    var transactionDomain = Mapper.Map<TransactionViewModel, Transaction>(viewModel);
                    _unitOfWork.TransactionRepository.Add(transactionDomain, userId);
                    _unitOfWork.Save();

                    return Json(0);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var msg = new StringBuilder();

                if (ex is DbEntityValidationException)
                {
                    var errors = ex as DbEntityValidationException;
                    foreach (var err in errors.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors.Select(get => get.ErrorMessage)))
                    {
                        msg.AppendLine(err);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    msg.AppendLine(ex.Message);
                }

                return Json(msg.ToString());
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                _unitOfWork.TransactionRepository.Remove(id);
                _unitOfWork.Save();

                return Json(0);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var msg = new StringBuilder();

                if (ex is DbEntityValidationException)
                {
                    var errors = ex as DbEntityValidationException;
                    foreach (var err in errors.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors.Select(get => get.ErrorMessage)))
                    {
                        msg.AppendLine(err);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    msg.AppendLine(ex.Message);
                }

                return Json(msg.ToString());
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _unitOfWork.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

**Context**

```
using MyMoney.DAL.EntityCfg;
using MyMoney.Domain.Entities;
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyMoney.DAL.Context
{
    public class MyMoneyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyMoneyContext()
            : base("MyMoney")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Transaction> Transations { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TransactionConfig());
        }

        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Select(x => x))
            {
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entry.Property("Date").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
                }

                if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    entry.Property("Date").IsModified = false;
                    entry.Property("UserId").IsModified = false;
                }
            }

            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Se precisarem de mais informação eu coloco aqui.
Grato pela ajuda desde já.

**Novas Informações:**

Descobri o motivo do disposed. O contexto que uso quando chamo o **SaveChanges**, no controller é **_unitOfWork.Save()**, é uma instancia diferente do contexto que está no repositório. Isso é, no **UnitOfWork** é injetado uma instancia do contexto e no repositório é injetado outra instancia do contexto.
A solução pode ser chamar o **SaveChanges** no contexto do repositório, mas em minha opinião isso está errado, isso deve ficar dentro do **UnitOfWork** mesmo.
Outra solução é injetar o **UnitiOfWork** dentro do repositório e assim utilizar o contexto do **UnitOfWork**, só que no design que está ficaria assim:

**UnitOfWork**

```
public UnitOfWork(MyMoneyContext context, ITransaction transactionRepository)
{
   this._context = context;
   this._transactionRepository = transactionRepository;
}

public MyMoneyContext DbContext
{
   get
   {
      return _context;
   }
}
```

**RepositoryBase**

```
protected MyMoneyContext db;

public RepositoryBase(IUnitOfWork db)
{
   this.db = db.DbContext;
}
```

**TransactionRepository**

```
public TransactionRepository(IUnitOfWork db) : base(db)
{
}
```

O problema ai é que crio uma depenica circular que vai causar um **stackoverflow**. Alguém tem uma ideia melhor de como resolver?

Comment: Acho que será uma boa ideia mostrar também o `RepositoryBase`

Comment: @BrunoCosta, adicionei o RepositoryBase.

Comment: Esta UnitOfWork é uma aberração. Livre-se disso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, obrigado pelo link, as informações são muito interessante, algo que se deve refletir! Porem no meu caso eu realmente quero criar mais camadas de abstração, por isso não serve como resposta para minha questão.

Comment: Não é uma "resposta para a sua questão", é uma recomendação. Há uma insistência de se usar isso, que é um anti-padrão, encorajada por alguns, mas é totalmente incorreto. Além disso, sua resposta não responde à questão no erro que você tem.

Comment: O que mais quero é uma resposta melhor do que encontrei. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A  melhor solução para meu caso foi esta:

**UnitOfWork**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private MyMoneyContext context = new MyMoneyContext();
        private TransactionRepository transactionRepository;

        public TransactionRepository TransactionRepository
        {
            get
            {
                if (transactionRepository == null)
                {
                    transactionRepository = new TransactionRepository(context);
                }

                return transactionRepository;
            }
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Instancio o contexto no **UnitOfWork** e crio um método que instancia o repositório passando a instancia do contexto, isso é, não injeto mais nada no **UnitOfWork**. Logicamente também alterei os construtores dos repositórios para receber o contexto e não o UnitOfWork e continuo usando o **SaveChanges** nele como eu queria. Tudo funcionando aqui. :)