# Unit Of Work + IoC + IDisposable

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, entity-framework, injeção-de-dependência, ioc

Estou montando um projeto que utilizo ***UoW*** para facilitar a questão de transações. Em alguns cenários, utilizo vários repositórios, persistindo os dados na memória para salvar de uma só vez no BD utilizando um método Commit() da classe **UnitOfWork**. Estou também utilizando ***Entity Framework***, ao qual recebo uma Interface **IDbContext** no construtor do **UnitOfWork** e utilizo um conjunto de ***DbSet*** e o próprio **SaveChanges()** do framework para aderir o **Commit()**.

Agora vamos para a dúvida, não estou utilizando a interface ***IDisposable*** no UnitOfWork e queria saber se há necessidade já que estou utilizando **IoC** (com SimpleInjector). Um outro ponto é que vi muitos artigos utilizando o IDisposable nos repositórios, mas estou utilizando uma única instância por request, se eu fechar a conexão do Banco de Dados e na mesma requisição chamar um outro repositório talvez solte uma **Exception**. Creio que o que me falta seja conhecimento em comparação a isto.

Interface IUnitOfWork:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    void Commit();
}
```

Classe UnitOfWork

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork //Deveria implementar IDisposable aqui ?
{
    private readonly IDbContext _dbContext;

    public UnitOfWork(IDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Interface IDbContext:

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    int SaveChanges();
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class MeuDbContext : IDbContext
{
    public MeuDbContext() : base("MeuDbContextConnectionString") 
    {
        //Configurações ...
    }

    public DbSet<ClasseA> ClasseA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClasseB> ClasseB { get; set; }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException exception)
        {
            var ex = HandleDbEntityValidationException(exception);
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException exception)
        {
            var ex = HandleDbUpdateException(exception);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

IoC:

```
public class MeuProjetoBootstrap
{
    public static void RegisterServices(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IDbContext, QueensberryDbContext (Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    }
}
```

Cenário:

```
public class MeuExemploApplication()
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private readonly IClasseARepositorio _classeARepositorio;
    private readonly IClasseBRepositorio _classeBRepositorio;

    public void MeuExemploApplication(IUnitOfWork uow, IClasseARepositorio classeARepositorio, IClasseBRepositorio classeBRepositorio) 
    {
        //Utilizacao de IoC
        _uow = uow;
        _classeARepositorio = classeARepositorio;
        _classeBRepositorio = classeBRepositorio;
    }

    public void Adicionar(DadosViewModel model)
    {
        // Deveria utilizar *using* aqui ? Algo como: 
        // using(_uow) { ... código citado abaixo ... }

        var classeA = new ClasseA()
        {
            PropriedadeUm = model.PropriedadeUmA,
            PropriedadeDois = model.PropriedadeDoisA
        }

        _classeARepositorio.Adicionar(classeA);

        var classeB = new ClasseB()
        {
            PropriedadeUm = model.PropriedadeUmB,
            PropriedadeDois = model.PropriedadeDoisB
        }

        _classeBRepositorio.Adicionar(classeB);

        _uow.Commit();

    }
}
```

Não estou utilizando a interface ***IDisposable*** em lugar nenhum. Onde devo fechar a conexão com o Banco de Dados ? Na classe Unit Of Work ? E se sim, como fazer isso utilizando IoC e sem que haja a necessidade de chamar um método Dispose() para cada operação.

**OBS:** Não creio que seja em um repositório, pois se eu chamar dois repositórios em uma única operação, talvez o primeiro repositório chamado feche a conexão com o Banco de Dados e como estou utilizando uma instância por ***request*** isso daria um problema para o repositório seguinte.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696

Comment: Legal... Porém, ficou uma dúvida. Em um cenário como DDD (onde o próprio Eric Evans ensina sobre repositórios), você acha que é uma má prática mesmo sendo utilizado nesta questão ? Sendo a melhor prática substituir por Extesions Methods os repositórios ? Creio que o livro tenha sido criado antes mesmo do C# oferecer recursos como o Extesions Methods e ele se baseia em uma ferramenta como o Java que eu não sei se possuí está alternativa. Se puder me tirar essa dúvida, agradeço.

Comment: "você acha que é uma má prática mesmo sendo utilizado nesta questão?". Sim. Você leu a resposta?

Comment: "Sendo a melhor prática substituir por Extesions Methods os repositórios ? Creio que o livro tenha sido criado antes mesmo do C# oferecer recursos como o Extesions Methods e ele se baseia em uma ferramenta como o Java que eu não sei se possuí está alternativa." A pergunta não é sobre Java: é sobre C# usando Entity Framework. Não existe extensions para Java. Não existe Entity Framework para Java. Se estivéssemos falando sobre Java e repositórios em Java, não haveria qualquer problema de práticas na sua questão. Peço novamente que releia a resposta vinculada à sua pergunta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não sei qual framework de injeção de dependência você está utilizando, mas normalmente esses frameworks tem algo chamado **lifestyle** (que você mesmo mostrou em seu código), e dependendo do lifestyle, o próprio `container` chamará o `Dispose()` para você.

Normalmente eles vem com essas possíveis configurações:

- **Transitório (transient)**: uma instância nova cada vez que for necessário injetar o objeto
- **Singleton**: uma instância única para a aplicação. No caso de uma aplicação web, por exemplo, a mesma instância será utilizada para várias requests (ou seja, enquanto o processo existir).
- **Por Thread**: uma instância por thread (eu particularmente nunca precisei usar isso)
- **Por Request**: será utilizada uma nova instância para cada request, mas esse obviamente não funciona com aplicações WPF e Win Forms, por exemplo.

O correto é você estudar o framework que você está utilizando e entender se ele também funciona assim, eu utilizo o Ninject e sei que ele funciona assim.

> Veja [aqui](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes) uma tabela mostrando como os scopes do Ninject funcionam.

---

No caso do Ninject para as situações acima, ele só não chamará o `Dispose()` automaticamente para o transitório, sendo que a classe que receberá a dependência deverá implementar o `IDisposable` e fazer o dispose dos *recursos* (ex: `DbContext`) por conta própria.

### Repository Pattern + DbContext + Dispose onde?

É bem comum ver pessoas que estão estudando/aprendendo (assim como eu) lerem a respeito de EF + Repository Pattern + IoC + UoW, olhando assim até parece uma fórmula perfeita para uma boa arquitetura, mas isso é apenas conceitual.

Na verdade, para evitarmos complexidade ao trabalhar com o `DbContext`, o ideal é garantir que para a execução de uma ação (ex: cadastrar usuário, aprovar pagamento, processar pedido, liberar produtos) seja utilizado a mesma instância de `DbContext`. Isso porque a menos que você interfira nas configurações dele, quando você carrega uma lista de entidades, o EF, por exemplo, cria classes proxy e já começa a observar quaisquer mudanças nesses objetos. Ele é inteligente ao ponto de caso você venha a mudar quaisquer objetos no seu grafo, ou seja, classes filhas, netas e etc, ao executar o `SaveChanges()` ele vai saber exatamente o que fazer.

Mas alguns exemplos de *repository pattern* recebem uma instância do `DbContext` em seu construtor, e acabam tendo algum método genérico (muitas vezes em um `RepositoryBase`) assim:

```
public Repository(IDbContext db)
{
    this._db = db;
}

public void Update(T entity)
{
    this._db.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
    this._db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Qual a necessidade desse `Attach()` e dessa alteração manual no `State` do `entry`? Simples, esse objeto foi recuperado através de outra instância do `DbContext`. Se tivesse sido utilizada a mesma instância, nem precisaria existir esse método `Update()`. Mas como você vai garantir que a mesma instância de `DbContext` vai ser utilizada durante toda a execução da sua ação, até chamar o `SaveChanges` (quando for o caso)?

### Ioc FTW?

Daí viram que seria possível resolver esse problema com o IoC, onde ele guardaria uma instância única do `DbContext` e injetaria a mesma instância em diferentes repositórios. Daí não tem mais necessidade de manualmente utilizar `Attach`, `Detach` e nem desse `Update` nos repositórios.

Como vários repositórios podem compartilhar o mesmo `DbContext`, nenhum deles deve chamar o `Dispose()` dele, pois como vamos ter certeza que nenhum outro ainda precisará dele? Iremos configurar uma instância Singleton? Não é exatamente uma boa ideia manter um `DbContext` por aí vagando pela aplicação o tempo todo (posso estar enganado).

Então, vamos definir que só precisaremos de uma determinada instância de `DbContext` até que nossa ação seja executada. As ações ficam na camada de aplicação, como exemplo o teu método **Adicionar**. O método adicionar vai utilizar todos os repositórios que quiser, de alguma forma chamar o `SaveChanges` e dar o `Dispose()` no `DbContext`, além disso garantir que esse mesmo `DbContext` vai ser utilizado somente durante a execução das ações daquela aplicação. Para isso, ao invés de injetar os repositórios na camada de aplicação, uma ideia seria criar uma classe única para cuidar dessa única instância do `DbContext` que deverá ser usado somente para aquela ação em particular, e ela também injetará esse DbContext nos repositórios. Já que essa classe vai representar uma execução da aplicação, vamos chamá-la de **UnitOfWork** (unidade de trabalho):

```
public class UnitOfWork: IDisposable
{
    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        this._db = new QueensberryDbContext();
    }

    public RepositoryA GetRepositoryA()
    {
        return new RepositoryA(_db);
    }

    public IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return _db.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _db.Dispose();
    }
}

public class MeuExemploApplication: IDisposable
{

    public MeuExemploApplication(UnitOfWork uow) 
    {
        this._uow = uow;
    }

    public void Adicionar()
    {
        var coisas = _uow.GetRepositorioA().GetAlgumaCoisa(); // por repositório
        var usuarios = _uow.Set<Usuario>().ToList(); // acessando diretamente o set
        // faz tudo o que tem que fazer no método "Adicionar"
        _uow.Commit(); // save changes
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _uow.Dispose(); // dispose uow, que internamente fará dispose do DbContext
    }
}
```

Perceba que ao trabalhar com o **UnitOfWork**, ele fica responsável por gerenciar o tempo de vida do `DbContext`, pois ele representa uma unidade de trabalho, e idealmente o `DbContext` deveria ser mantido somente até a execução dessa tarefa/action/ação (como quiser chamar os use cases de sua aplicação). Nesse caso, você não tem o `DbContext` no seu container de injeção de dependência, e o `UnitOfWork` deve ser configurado por **Scope**, ou seja, sempre que uma aplicação for instanciada, uma nova instância exclusiva para aquela aplicação do `UnitOfWork` (que consequentemente terá seu próprio `DbContext`) será injetada, e a aplicação é quem cuida do seu exclusivo `UnitOfWork` chamando o `Dispose()` por conta própria.

### Aplicações Web

No caso de uma aplicação web, onde o asp.net gerencia todo o fluxo de requisições, eu particularmente **não vejo a menor necessidade de utilizar UnitOfWork**. Isso porque cada requisição pode ser entendida como uma *unidade de trabalho*, daí você configura o `DbContext` no IoC novamente, mas utiliza a opção **Per Request**.

---

Eu particularmente estou de acordo com o **Cigano**, eu só utilizo Repository Pattern em minhas aplicações como uma forma de encapsular e reutilizar queries complexas (bem como acessá-las dentro do Domain), mas isso poderia ser substituído por métodos de extensão (conforme observado pelo Cigano), nem utilizo também o `UnitOfWork`, porque meu acesso a dados sempre é feito através de uma aplicação web (Web API ou WCF), e caso eu venha a precisar de um WPF ou WinForms, eu consumo a API/WCF. Por isso até o momento não tive necessidade de utilizar o **UnitOfWork**.

Eu acho que o Repository Pattern adiciona sim uma complexidade, e precisa ser bem analisado se vale a pena, o [link com a resposta do Cigano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696) é excelente. Eu entendo que em uma arquitetura orientada a microservices, acaba sendo desnecessário utilizar. Mas se você está montando uma super API, talvez valha a pena, pois as chances de você precisar reutilizar um código são altas.

KISS

Comment: Obrigado, jovem. Votaria duas vezes se pudesse.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu que agradeço pelo link nos comentários. Já guardei o link para distribuir a alguns amigos desenvolvedores (inclusive na equipe onde trabalho). Votei e também votaria mais vezes!

Comment: Obrigado cara. Estou utilizando Simple Injector e percebi que realmente, após a execução de uma View (MVC), ele entra no Dispose de forma automática. Estava utilizando buscas através do UoW, mas já refatorei o código para não fazer buscas pelo UoW pois estava sobrecarregando a memória, então pra qualquer tipo de busca crio uma instância e já dou dispose em seguida (verifiquei que até o consumo de memória do pool da aplicação).