# Projeto ASP.NET MVC usando EntityFramework

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, oracle

Galera, uma pergunta bem iniciante, eu fiz um projeto ASP.NET MVC usando o EntityFrameWork, fiz utilizando o padrão UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWorks : IDisposable
{

    // Context
    private AgendaContext _context = new AgendaContext();

    //propfull tab tab 
    private IClienteRepository _clienteRepository;

    public IClienteRepository ClienteRepository
    {

        get
        {
            if(this._clienteRepository == null)
            {
                this._clienteRepository = new ClienteRepository(_context);
            }
            return _clienteRepository;
        }

    }

    //SaveChanges
    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool _disposed = false;

    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this._disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this._disposed = true;
    }

    //Fechar a conexão... liberar o recurso
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true); //Libera a conexão do context
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this); //Finaliza o UnitOfWork
    }
}
```

}

Quero saber se eu consigo utilizar o banco de dados MySQL ou Oracle nesse projeto com Entity Framework. E como eu faço pra configurar o banco de dados, desde o primeiro passo, eu crio um banco de dados dentro do projeto mesmo? Quais são os códigos.

Comment: Sim, é possível, mas sua pergunta foge completamente do escopo do site.

Comment: Entity Framework já implementa Unit of Work. Você não precisa fazer isso de novo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696