# Utilizando EF e Dapper no mesmo projeto

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dapper

Estou fazendo um simples `insert` de uma classe de usuário, o mesmo está demorando quase 10 segundos para gravar as informações. Assim tentei encontrar outras soluções para resolver meu problema de performance e encontrei o `Dapper`.

Minha dúvida existe alguma forma de utilizar os dois `ORMs` em meu projeto? pois gostei do EF na questão de mapeamento e das migrations pois utilizo como *Code First.*

Para chegar nessa conclusão de lentidão utilizei esse [artigo](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/dapper-vs-entity-framework-vs-ado-net-performance-benchmarking/) como referencial  teórico.

As classes que estou utilizando:

**Usuario**:

```
   [Table("Usuario", Schema = "public")]
    public class Usuario : PessoaBase
    {
        private string login;
        private string senha;

        public Usuario(string nome, string email, int status, string login, string senha, DateTime dtCriacao) : base( nome, status, dtCriacao, email)
        {
            this.login = login;
            this.senha = senha;

        }

        [DisplayName("Login")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Login deve ser preenchido!")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Index("Ix_UsuarioLogin", IsUnique = true)]
        public string Login
        {
            get { return login; }
            set { login = value; }
        }

        [DisplayName("Senha")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Senha deve ser preechida!")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Senha
        {
            get { return senha; }
            set { senha = value; }
        }

    }
```

**Repositório**:

```
public abstract class Repositorio<TEntity> : IDisposable,
           IRepositorio<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        BaseContexto ctx = new BaseContexto();
        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return ctx.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public IQueryable<TEntity> Get(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
        {
            return GetAll().Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
        }

        public TEntity Find(params object[] key)
        {
            return ctx.Set<TEntity>().Find(key);
        }

        public void Atualizar(TEntity obj)
        {
            ctx.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public void SalvarTodos()
        {
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Adicionar(TEntity obj)
        {
            ctx.Set<TEntity>().Add(obj);
        }

        public void Excluir(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
        {
            ctx.Set<TEntity>()
                .Where(predicate).ToList()
                .ForEach(del => ctx.Set<TEntity>().Remove(del));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            ctx.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

*Pra salvar um usuário apenas faço dessa forma:*

```
uDal.Adicionar(u);
 uDal.SalvarTodos();
```

*OBS:* Estou utilizando o NetFramework 4.5, visual studio 2013 e BD postgresql.

Comment: O principal seria identificar a lentidão, o Entity Framework não é para ser tão lento 10 segundos é muita coisa, deve ter problemas como está na programação, sobre a camada repositório já tem problemas como você a fez, porque para cada item vai ter um contexto diferente, esse é um problema de muitos fazem, tem que ser feito um pouco diferente, e alguns desenvolvedores são contra, mas, eu vejo na sua pergunta que o problema é maior, pense 10 segundos é tempo demais. Dá uma olhada no seu projeto a fundo, só uma dica.

Comment: Mais uma coisa eu uso EF nos meus projetos e não tem problema nenhum na hora da gravação ou até recuperação que é mais custoso, funciona muito bem inclusive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Minha dúvida existe alguma forma de utilizar os dois ORMs em meu projeto? pois gostei do EF na questão de mapeamento e das migrations pois utilizo como Code First.

Sim, olha só:

```
var query = db.Database.Connection.Query(...); // <- Isto é Dapper em cima da connection do Entity Framework.
```

Lembrando que Dapper é um *framework*-extensão implementado em cima de `IDbConnection`.

PS: Abandone repositório. [Já falei sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696).

Comment: Sim eu li vários tópicos já seu CIgano falando sobre os repositórios, mas nao entendia o motivo. Um deles seria problema lentidão também?

Comment: Veja minha resposta sem leitura dinâmica. Eu levei anos pra escrevê-la, com experiências que tive em projetos e empresas pelas quais passei. Simplesmente não vale a pena usar. Causa lentidão se você observar a Falácia 1.

Comment: Certo obrigado, mas voce utiliza EF em seus projetos? Outra questão, posso (é certo, viável)  utilizar EF apenas para o mapeamento e para controle de versões com as migrações, mas dai utilizar Dapper para manipulação de dados e deixar o EF de lado ?

Comment: " voce utiliza EF em seus projetos?", sim. " posso (é certo, viável) utilizar EF apenas para o mapeamento e para controle de versões com as migrações, mas dai utilizar Dapper para manipulação de dados e deixar o EF de lado?", vai te dar mais trabalho, mas sim, pode. Eu tenho um curso sobre ASP.NET MVC com um capítulo sobre Dapper em que explico tudo isso.

Comment: Cigano onde consigo o curso? Se você tiver vários cursos e puder passar o link, que eu adquiro eles. pois estou casando de achar cursos que ensinam errado :X

Comment: Comigo mesmo. [Me procure no Facebook](https://facebook.com/cigano.m.mendez). [A ementa é essa](http://www.codingcraft.com.br/2016/08/10/coding-craft-asp-net-mvc-e-asp-net-web-api-modulo-1-turma-de-10-de-setembro-de-2016/), mas as aulas são individuais, e você marca dia e hora de aula.