# Como inserir um registro já existente no Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-v1

Em certo ponto do sistema alguns registros são selecionados e devem ser replicados alterando apenas um valor.

Neste ponto estou selecionando os registros que preciso inserir:

```
listaRegistros = listaRegistros .GroupBy(r => r.Id)
                        .Select(grp => grp.First()).ToList();
```

Logo depois utilizo esses registros selecionados acima para inserir novos registros na tabela:

```
foreach (var orgao in listaOrgaosASeremAdicionados)
{
    foreach (var registro in listaRegistros)
        registro.Orgao = orgao;
    new RegistrosMeService().InsertListaRegistrosMe(listaRegistros);
}
```

Aqui está o `InsertListaRegistrosMe` da classe `RegistrosMeService`:

```
protected EFSpecificRepository<TB_RegistrosMe, Entities> _repository;
protected EFSpecificRepository<TB_RegistrosMe, Entities> Repository
{
    get
    {
        if (_repository == null)
            _repository = new EFSpecificRepository<TB_RegistrosMe, Entities>();
        return _repository;
    }
}

public int InsertListaRegistrosMe(List<TB_RegistrosMe> listaMe)
{
    Repository.InsertList(listaMe);
    Repository.SaveChanges();
}
```

O primeiro `loop`, onde é feito a inserção, é para informar para quantos órgãos a lista de registros será adicionada, mais de um pode ter sido selecionado.

A unica alteração realizada no registro é a que pode ser verificada no `loop`, que é a alteração do `registro.Orgao`.

O problema é que no Insert ocorre o erro:

> "Já existe um objeto com a mesma chave no ObjectStateManager. O objeto
>   existente está no estado Unchanged. Um objeto só poderá ser adicionado
>   novamente ao ObjectStateManager se estiver no estado adicionado."

Já tentei alterar o Id, mas ao tentar fazer isso também ocorre um erro:

> A propriedade 'Id' faz parte das informações de chave do objeto e não
>   pode ser modificada.

Pelo que entendo esse problema ocorre por que estou observando um registro que já existe no EF e por segurança ele não permite que eu adicione esse registro pois o considera duplicado, correto?

Mas como eu poderia resolver isso sem precisar criar um novo objeto no EF 3.5 (v1)? É possível alterar o `ObjectStateManager` de forma que ele permita que faça a inserção?

Comment: @jbueno, verifiquei pelo meu `System.Data.Entity` e é essa versão mesmo. Outro fato estranho se realmente não existir é a `tag` estar aqui no SOpt, mas realmente quando pesquiso por essa versão não encontro nada concreto sobre ela. Mas achei [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework)

Comment: O que tem em `RegistrosMeService.InsertListaRegistrosMe`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez é onde estão todos os métodos de select, insert, saveChanges. Quer que edito com o método `InsertListaRegistrosMe`?

Comment: Sim, por favor. É aí que está o problema.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez adicionei a pegunta.

Comment: Outra coisa: não existe EF3.5. O primeiro EF estável é o 4.1, que deve ser o que você está usando.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez então a verificação de versão pelo `System.Data.Entity` não está correta? Como identifico a versão corretamente?

Comment: Biblioteca `EntityFramework`, no seu References, ou versão do arquivo `packages.config`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o registro precisa ser replicado, ou seja, reinserido, você não pode reinserir com o mesmo valor de chave primária. Precisa criar objetos novos a partir dos objetos que já existem. Ou seja:

```
var novaListaDeRegistros = new List<Registro>();

foreach (var orgao in listaOrgaosASeremAdicionados)
{
    foreach (var registro in listaRegistros) 
    {
        novaListaDeRegistros.Add(new Registro 
        {
            // Coloque aqui todas as propriedades de Registro, 
            // com exceção do RegistroId, que será novo.
            registro.Orgao = orgao;
        });
    }
}

new RegistrosMeService().InsertListaRegistrosMe(novaListaDeRegistros);
```

PS: [Livre-se desse repositório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696).

Comment: Cigano, já estava funcionando exatamente dessa maneira que sugeriu, mas achei que poderia evitar isso. Como sugeriu, a única forma de evitar vai ser me livrando desse repositório.

Answer (score 3):

O Entity Framework trabalha com coleções observáveis, ou seja, os registros que são retornados da sua consulta estão sendo "observados" pelo contexto para que, quando (e se) houver mudanças estas possam ser refletidas no banco de dados.

Usar o método `AsNoTracking()` deve resolver. Este método "avisa" ao contexto que não é preciso observar as mudanças nas entidades.

```
listaRegistros = listaRegistros.GroupBy(r => r.Id)
                    .Select(grp => grp.First()).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Comment: Não funciona. Parece que `AsNoTracking()` nem existia nessa versão. :(

Comment: Pois é, não parei pra pensar nisso. Veja se fazer `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` te ajuda. Isso deve ter o mesmo efeito.

Comment: Nada de `Configuration` no contexto também, omg! Da pra entender por que não acha nada de EF 3.5, ninguém devia usar!

Answer (score 3):

Você tem duas alternativas.

**Alternativa saudável:** clone os objetos que deseja copiar e salve os clones. A vantagem é que quem for ler o seu código para dar manutenção vai entender que era claramente a sua intenção ter novos objetos. Eu digo isso porque ao ler o código que você postou sem considerar o contexto da pergunta, eu juraria de pés juntos, pela minha alma e pela minha mãe, que você confundiu os termos *insert* e *update* e que a sua intenção na verdade era editar registros já existentes no banco de dados ao invés de inserir novos.

Ao inserir um objeto completamente novo no repositório, ele fica marcado como um novo objeto nas coleções internas do EF. Quando o contexto for salvo os novos objetos serão inseridos no banco de dados.

**Maneira McGyver:** essa maneira é muito feia. Sério. Se você fizer isso de propósito eu vou descobrir quem você é só para garantir que nunca vou apertar a sua mão. Vou adicionar essa forma aqui por motivos educacionais, porque muita gente faz isso **sem querer** quando começa a trabalhar com Entity Framework **em conjunto com ASP.NET**.

Simplesmente carregue os objetos em um contexto. Feche o contexto. Agora abra outro contexto, adicione os objetos e salve. O novo contexto entenderá que os objetos são novos (pois não os observou durante a sua obtenção) e irá marcar todos para criação no banco de dados.

A maioria das pessoas quando inicia com ASP.NET não percebe que você tem um contexto diferente a cada requisição das páginas. As pessoas carregam os objetos em uma requisição GET e os alteram no processamento de uma requisição POST. Isso já levou a páginas e páginas de perguntas e respostas no Stack Overflow sobre duplicação de objetos ao se utilizar Entity Framework. Para a maioria das pessoas isso é um defeito, mas parece que no seu caso pode ser uma *feature* (a depender do ciclo de vida dos seus objetos).

Comment: Renan, já estou fazendo o Clone do objeto, mas queria saber se era possível fazer algo como o `AsNoTracking()` sugerido pelo @jbueno. Mas pelo jeito não é possível. Espero que possa apertar minha mão um dia se surgir a oportunidade!! hahah :D