# Atualização Many To Many Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Estou tendo problema na hora de fazer a atualização com relacionamento many to many.

Eu quero que no método atualizar ele atualize todas os campos do itemEntity também como os fornecedores.

Para exemplificar coloquei apenas o campo descrição e fornecedores conforme a imagem da tela.

No meu código abaixo se eu removo a linha que da o erro (mostrado abaixo) ele grava apenas os fornecedores.

Eu tentei setar a itemEntity como modificado mas eu recebo o erro.

Alguém pode por favor me ajudar?

***Minha Tela***

[image: Minha Tela]

***Erro***

Attaching an entity of type 'Domain.Entities.ItemEntity' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Tabela***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Relacionamento***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Codigo***

```
    public override ItemEntity Atualizar(ItemEntity entity)
    {
        var novos = new List<FornecedorEntity>(entity.Fornecedores);

        entity.Fornecedores = _dbContext.TbItem
           .Where(p => p.Id == entity.Id).FirstOrDefault().Fornecedores;

        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        //Sem a linha acima ele funciona mais não atualiza as demais propriedades do ItemEntity, 
        //atualiza somente os fornecedores.

        var deletetadoFornecedores = entity.Fornecedores
            .Except(novos).ToList();

        deletetadoFornecedores.ForEach(c => entity.Fornecedores.Remove(c));

        var AdicionadoFornecedores = novos
            .Except(entity.Fornecedores).ToList();

        foreach (FornecedorEntity c in AdicionadoFornecedores)
        {
            if (_dbContext.Entry(c).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                _dbContext.TbFornecedor.Attach(c);
            }

            entity.Fornecedores.Add(c);
        }

        _dbContext.SaveChanges();      

        return entity;
    }
```

***Editado***

Esse código faz exatamente o que preciso, porem tenho que ficar mapeando as propriedades.

```
    public override ItemEntity Atualizar(ItemEntity entity)
    {
        var itemExistente = _dbContext.TbItem
                .Find(entity.Id);

        itemExistente.Descricao = entity.Descricao;
        itemExistente.Descricao1 = entity.Descricao1;
        itemExistente.Descricao2 = entity.Descricao2;
        itemExistente.Descricao3 = entity.Descricao3;
        itemExistente.Descricao4 = entity.Descricao4;
        //Esse mapeamento acima não tem como fazer de forma automatica?
        //Toda vez que eu criar uma nova propriedade vou ter que lembrar de vir aqui e alterar
        //isso gera maior dificuldade na manutenão e aumenta a chance de esquecer e gerar um bug.


        var fornecedoresDeletados = itemExistente.Fornecedores
            .Except(entity.Fornecedores).ToList();

        var fornecedoresAdicionados = entity.Fornecedores
            .Except(itemExistente.Fornecedores).ToList();

        fornecedoresDeletados.ForEach(c => itemExistente.Fornecedores.Remove(c));

        foreach (FornecedorEntity c in fornecedoresAdicionados)
        {
            if (_dbContext.Entry(c).State == EntityState.Detached)
                _dbContext.TbFornecedor.Attach(c);

            itemExistente.Fornecedores.Add(c);
        }

        _dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return entity;
    }
```

Comment: Mauricio, no lugar da imagem do erro poderia por a mensagem?

Comment: Posso mais qual mensagem?

Comment: Não sei kkkk, é que não consigo ver as imagens daqui :(. Não é uma mensagem que tem na imagem do Erro?

Comment: rsrs, Da um clique nela que ela fica grande.Coloquei em cima de qualquer forma.

Comment: Não, não é isso, a rede que estou o imgur é bloqueado. E também é importante por o texto, pois se alguém pesquisar pelo erro é mais fácil chegar até aqui. :)

Comment: Acho que o único problema é não estar usando o `EntityState.Modified` antes de salvar as mudanças.

Comment: O problema é bem maior. Já estou elaborando alguma coisa.

Comment: Opa vlw Cigano, quando eu removo EntityState.Modified ele só atualiza os fornecedores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está colocando o `Item` duas vezes em contexto, e seus `Fornecedor`es também:

```
    entity.Fornecedores = _dbContext.TbItem
       .Where(p => p.Id == entity.Id).FirstOrDefault().Fornecedores;
```

O que eu faria no seu lugar são dois *ViewModels*:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public ICollection<FornecedorViewModel> Fornecedores { get; set; }
}

public class FornecedorViewModel
{
    public int FornecedorId { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public bool Selecionado { get; set; }
}
```

Aqui eu faria:

```
public override ItemEntity Atualizar(ItemViewModel entity)
{
    var item = _dbContext.TbItem
                         .Include(i => i.Fornecedores)
                         .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == entity.Id);

    // Excluídos
    var idsFornecedoresExcluidos = item.Fornecedores
                                       .Where(f => !f.Selecionado)
                                       .Select(f => f.Id)
                                       .ToList();

    foreach (var fornecedor in item.Fornecedores.Where(f => idsFornecedoresExcluidos.Contains(f.Id)))
    {
        item.Fornecedores.Remove(fornecedor);
    }

    __dbContext.SaveChanges();

    // Incluídos
    var idsFornecedoresIncluidos = item.Fornecedores
                                       .Where(f => f.Selecionado)
                                       .Select(f => f.Id)
                                       .ToList();

    foreach (var novoFornecedor in __dbContext.Fornecedores.Where(f => idsFornecedoresIncluidos.Contains(f.Id)))
    {
        item.Fornecedores.Add(novoFornecedor);
    }

    __dbContext.SaveChanges();

    // Alterando item.
    item.Nome = entity.Nome;
    _dbContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    __dbContext.SaveChanges();

    return item;
}
```

Como são várias operações, um escopo transacional aqui seria interessante:

```
public override ItemEntity Atualizar(ItemViewModel entity)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) // Adicione a referência para System.Transactions para ter isso funcionando
    {
        var item = _dbContext.TbItem
                             .Include(i => i.Fornecedores)
                             .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == entity.Id);

        // Excluídos
        var idsFornecedoresExcluidos = item.Fornecedores
                                           .Where(f => !f.Selecionado)
                                           .Select(f => f.Id)
                                           .ToList();

        foreach (var fornecedor in item.Fornecedores.Where(f => idsFornecedoresExcluidos.Contains(f.Id)))
        {
            item.Fornecedores.Remove(fornecedor);
        }

        __dbContext.SaveChanges();

        // Incluídos
        var idsFornecedoresIncluidos = item.Fornecedores
                                           .Where(f => f.Selecionado)
                                           .Select(f => f.Id)
                                           .ToList();

        foreach (var novoFornecedor in __dbContext.Fornecedores.Where(f => idsFornecedoresIncluidos.Contains(f.Id)))
        {
            item.Fornecedores.Add(novoFornecedor);
        }

        __dbContext.SaveChanges();

        // Alterando item.
        item.Nome = entity.Nome;
        _dbContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        __dbContext.SaveChanges();

        scope.Complete(); // Não esqueça do `scope.Complete()` para completar a transação.
        return item;
    }
}
```

Se precisar de ajuda sobre como carregar o *ViewModel*, só se manifestar por comentário.

Comment: não tem como fazer todas operações com um único _dbContext.SaveChanges(); ? estou usando UnitOfWork que no final de tudo eu chamo o _dbContext.SaveChanges();, depois que eu resolvesse o problema eu ia remover o _dbContext.SaveChanges(); dessa classe.

Comment: Por que está usando UnitOfWork? [Leia isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696).

Comment: Estou utilizando uma arquitetura DDD que estou aprendendo e nem sempre todas as alterações estarão dentro do mesmo repositório.

Comment: Consegui fazer de uma outra forma conforme o link , vou postar o código e ai vc me responde sobre minha duvida que vou destacar, só um momento. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-many-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: da uma olha no ultimo trecho de código, tem uma duvida la.

Comment: DDD, né? Bom, boa sorte com sua implementação. Minha ajuda acaba aqui.

Comment: @MauricioFerraz Te aconselho a ler o artigo que o Cigano referênciou no comentario dele, resolveu muitos problemas que eu tinha e pode te ajudar a ter um entendimento melhor de todo o projeto.

Comment: Estou lendo, Obrigado Cigano por sua ajuda e aos demais.