# Inserção de dados EntityFramework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho 3 Entity, onde são Paises, Estados e Cidades.
Estou realizando o Crud da entity Cidade, e ao salvar está pedindo o relacionamento de Estados e Paises, mas isso eu não preciso, pois tenho uma propriedade chamada EstadoHandle na entity Cidade para realizar o insert, por exemplo:

> O erro que ocorre é que diz que a entity pais não existe, porque estado se relaciona com pais, e cidade relaciona com estado, nesse caso ao inserir tem como tirar esse relacionamento para não pedir o preenchimento da entity Pais no estado que estou selecionando na entity cidade ?
>
> Entity Cidade

```
public class Cidades : EntityBase
{
    public Cidades()
    {
        Estado = new Estados();
    }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public int EstadoHandle { get; set; }
    public Estados Estado { get; set; }       
}
```

> Mapeamento da Entity

```
public class CidadesMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cidades>
{
    public CidadesMapping ()
    {
        ToTable("CIDADES");

        HasKey(x => x.Handle);

        Property(x => x.Descricao)
            .HasMaxLength(150)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(x => x.Sigla)
            .HasMaxLength(3)
            .IsRequired();

        HasRequired(x => x.Estado)
            .WithMany(x => x.Cidades)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.EstadoHandle);    
    }           
}
```

> Criando uma nova Cidade e Realizando o Insert que chama o método abaixo.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Estados estado = Entity<Estados>.GetByHandle(10);

        Cidades cidade = new Cidades();
        cidade.Handle = 50;
        cidade.Descricao = "CIDADE TESTE";
        cidade.Sigla = "TES";
        cidade.Estado = estado;
        cidade.EstadoHandle = estado.Handle;
        cidade.Insert();

    }   

    public static void Insert(this EntityBase entity)
    {
        try
        {
            DbSet dbSet = _context.Set(entity.GetType());
            dbSet.Add(entity);
            _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            string msng =  string.Empty;

            foreach (var error in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                msng += "Entity: " + error.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name;
                msng += "\n";
                msng += "State: " + error.Entry.State;
                msng += "\n";

                foreach(var erro in error.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    msng += "Property: " + erro.PropertyName;
                    msng += "\n";
                    msng += "Erro: " + erro.ErrorMessage;
                }
            }
            throw new Exception(msng);
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nicola Bogar pare de adicionar complexibilidade desnecessária ao seu código.

a classe `Entity<T>` e extensões como `Insert(this EntityBase entity)` só lhe trarar problemas.

No seu caso em especifico, `Entity<Estados>` por ser uma classe estática, não tem acesso ao seu `_context`, então deverá criar um novo contexto para poder realizar a consulta, desta forma o `_context` não está a rastrear o `estado`.

Caso utilize um padrão `Singleton` e o seu `_context` seja global, então terá problemas ainda maiores, pois o `EF` não foi projetado para ser usado desta forma.

quanto ao `Insert(this EntityBase entity)`, este código em nada acrescenta, apenas utilize o `DbSet<T>.AddAsync(T)`.

```
using (var contexto = new MyContext())
{
    await var estado = contexto.Estados.FindAsync(10);
    var cidade = new Cidades();
    cidade.Handle = 50;
    cidade.Descricao = "CIDADE TESTE";
    cidade.Sigla = "TES";
    cidade.Estado = estado;
    cidade.EstadoHandle = estado.Handle;
    await contexto.Cidades.AddAsync();
    await contexto.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Por fim, `Entity Framework` já implementa `Patterns` como `Unit of Work` e `Repository`, então não é uma boa adicionar à sua propria implementação de `Repository` encima do `EF`

Comment: @NicolaBogar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51536/2363