# Problema ao mapear entidades relacionadas com Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, fluent-api

Estou iniciando com o EF e estou tendo problemas para mapear o relacionamento entre minhas entidades.

## 1. Entidades

Existem duas entidades no projeto que estou utilizando para praticar o assunto. São elas:

- Usuário
- Time de futebol

Um usuário possui um único time de futebol e este possui **n** usuários.

#### 1.1 Usuário

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public string UsuarioNome { get; set; }
    public string UsuarioEmail { get; set; }

    public int TimeFutebolId { get; set; }
    public TimeFutebol TimeFutebol { get; set; }
}
```

Notem que criei a propriedade de navegação **TimeFutebol** para esta entidade. Também criei a propriedade TimeFutebolId, pois lendo a documentação do EF, encontrei uma recomendação sobre criar uma propriedade que será a chave estrangera.

#### 1.2 Time de futebol

```
public class TimeFutebol
{
    public int TimeFutebolId { get; set; }
    public string TimeFutebolNome { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }

    public TimeFutebol()
    {
        Usuarios = new List<Usuario>();
    }
}
```

Notem que também criei a propriedade de navegação **Usuarios** para esta entidade.

## 2. Banco de dados

#### 2.1 Tabela Usuario

Nome da tabela: Usuario

Inseri o usuário abaixo na tabela para teste

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### 2.2 Tabela TimeFutebol

Nome da tabela: TimeFutebol

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## DbContext

```
public class DataContext: DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("name=ConnString") { }

    public virtual DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TimeFutebol> TimesFutebol { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().ToTable("Usuario");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("UsuarioId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(x => x.Nome).HasColumnName("UsuarioNome");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(x => x.Email).HasColumnName("UsuarioEmail");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().Property(x => x.TimeFutebolId).HasColumnName("TimeFutebolId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().HasRequired(x => x.TimeFutebol).WithMany(x => x.Usuarios).HasForeignKey(x => x.TimeFutebolId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TimeFutebol>().ToTable("TimeFutebol");
        modelBuilder.Entity<TimeFutebol>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TimeFutebol>().Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("TimeFutebolId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<TimeFutebol>().Property(x => x.Nome).HasColumnName("TimeFutebolNome");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

## Resultado após rodar a aplicação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparem que a propriedade TimeFutebol, do primeiro objeto da lista **usuarios**, está vazia.Já a propriedade Usuarios, da lista de objetos **times**, não possui nenhum objeto (Count = 0).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, mostre o código em texto, não em imagens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incluí apenas o **virtual** nas propriedades de navegação e funcionou. Exemplo de uma das propriedades:

```
public virtual ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não colocou na pergunta o código que realiza a consulta dos dados utilizando o *context* do EF e isso dificulta a resposta.

Porém, muito provavelmente usando o **Include** conforme o código abaixo você conseguirá carregar o TimeFutebol relacionado ao Usuario.

Exemplo:

```
public ICollection<Usuario> GetAll()
{
    return context.Usuario.Include("TimeFutebol").ToList();
}
```

Comment: Renan, inclui as classes de consulta no post.

Comment: Usando o comando Include como exemplifiquei na resposta você conseguiu buscar os usuários com o seu respectivo time?

Answer (score 0):

**Mude sua classe TimeFutebol para:**

```
public class TimeFutebol
{
    public TimeFutebol()
    {
        Usuarios = new List<Usuario>();
    }

    public int TimeFutebolId { get; set; }
    public string TimeFutebolNome { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

Exemplo funcional: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9YnnEs

Comment: Cassio Alves, fiz o ajuste que você mencionou e atualizei o post em função dele.

Comment: após a mudança, deu certo?

Comment: Continuou apresentando o mesmo problema. A única diferença é que a propriedade Usuarios, da classe TimeFutebol, não aparece mais como null, pois a instanciei no construtor da sua classe (TimeFutebol).

Comment: e como você salva os dados? poderia colocar um exemplo. Obs: você não precisa implementar um repositório: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696

Comment: Bom, pra eu salvar os dados, antes eu tenho que trabalhar com eles. Para isso, eu preciso, primeiramente, popular minhas classes com os dados do banco. É aí que tá meu problema, eu não estou conseguindo popular minhas classes. Respondendo sua pergunta, para salvar os dados após eu realizar algum Add, Update ou Delete, eu vou chamar o método SaveAll que implementei na Interface IRepository.

Comment: poderia colocar um exemplo? pois é desnecessário ao meu ver.

Comment: Cassio, acho que isso vai sair do foco da minha dúvida, que é justamente como preencher minhas classes de forma automática com o Fluent API. Eu gostaria de resolver este problema primeiro, pois isso está me impedindo de continuar nos meus estudos. Posteriormente, se eu tiver algum problema ao salvar os dados, eu vou recorrer a vocês.

Comment: Esta certo. Poderia colocar o código que você usa para salvar, desde da instanciação da classe, ate o savechanges.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61406/discussion-between-cassio-alves-and-hudson-rodrigues).

Comment: Todas as classes, métodos, propriedades e interfaces que eu utilizo na aplicação que estou estudando, foram mostradas no post, com imagens e códigos. Não esqueci de nada. Só não coloquei o App.config, pois a conexão com o banco está sendo feita. Sei disso porque alguns dados das classes estão sendo preenchidos, como o nome do usuário e o email, por exemplo.