# Conflito entre objetos de mesmo tipo no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Possuo a seguinte classe:

```
public class Conteudo
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoria { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Obs { get; set; }
    public string Evidencias { get; set; }
    public string NSerie { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UsuarioAbertura")]
    public long? UsuarioAberturaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario UsuarioAbertura { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UsuarioFechamento")]
    public long? UsuarioFechamentoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario UsuarioFechamento { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DataHoraAbertura { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataHoraFechamento { get; set; }


    public long ManifestacaoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ManifestacaoId")]
    public virtual Manifestacao Manifestacao { get; set; }
}
```

Há dois tipos de *Usuario*: UsuarioFechamento e UsuarioAbertura. Um faz a abertura do Conteudo e outro faz o fechamento.

O problema é que se o usuário que faz o fechamento é diferente do que fez a abertura do Conteudo, ao tentar ler a base de dados, é apresentado o seguinte erro:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.'
```

Quando é o mesmo Usuario que faz a abertura e fechamento nenhum erro é apresentado.

Classe Usuario:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Apelido { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Conteudo> ConteudosAbertura { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Conteudo> ConteudosFechamento { get; set; }
}
```

Classe do Context:

```
public class EFContext : DbContext
{
    public EFContext() : base("Pos_Venda_SAC")
    {
        //this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Database.SetInitializer<EFContext>(
        new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFContext>()
        );
    }
    public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Conteudo> Conteudos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Manifestacao> Manifestacoes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Destinatario> Destinatarios { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .HasMany<Conteudo>(c => c.ConteudosAbertura)
            .WithOptional(c => c.UsuarioAbertura)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .HasMany<Conteudo>(c => c.ConteudosFechamento)
            .WithOptional(c => c.UsuarioFechamento)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
}
```

**ADICIONADO:**

Código que gera o erro:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using PosVendaSAC.POCO;
using PosVendaSAC.Classes;
using PosVendaSAC.Contexts;

namespace PosVendaSAC
{
    public partial class FrmDetalhesConteudo : Form
    {
        DAL_Conteudos dalConteudos = new DAL_Conteudos();
        DAL_Usuario dalUsuario = new DAL_Usuario();
        Conteudo conteudoAtual = new Conteudo();
        private string nomeUsuario;

        private bool textoEmailAlterado;
        private bool textoTelefoneAlterado;
        private bool textoRamalAlterado;
        private bool textoCelularAlterado;
        private bool textoContatoAlterado;

        public FrmDetalhesConteudo(long idRow)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            nomeUsuario = UsuarioLogado.Nome;
            conteudoAtual = dalConteudos.GetConteudoByID(idRow);
            PreencheCampos(conteudoAtual);
            DesabilitarEdicaoCampos();
            VerificarStatusFinalizado();
            textoEmailAlterado = false;
            textoTelefoneAlterado = false;
            textoRamalAlterado = false;
            textoCelularAlterado = false;
            textoContatoAlterado = false;
        }

        private void PreencheCampos(Conteudo conteudo)
        {
            txtEmpresaCliente.Text = conteudo.Manifestacao.Cliente.Empresa;
            txtContatoCliente.Text = conteudo.Manifestacao.Cliente.Contato;
            txtEmailCliente.Text = conteudo.Manifestacao.Cliente.Email;
            mskTelefoneCliente.Text = conteudo.Manifestacao.Cliente.Telefone;
            txtRamalCliente.Text = conteudo.Manifestacao.Cliente.Ramal;
            mskCelularCliente.Text = conteudo.Manifestacao.Cliente.Celular;
            txtCategoria.Text = conteudo.Categoria;
            txtSubCategoria.Text = conteudo.SubCategoria;
            txtConteudo.Text = conteudo.Descricao;
            txtStatus.Text = conteudo.Status;
            txtObs.Text = conteudo.Obs;
            txtEvidencias.Text = conteudo.Evidencias;
            lblTimeAbertura.Text = conteudo.DataHoraAbertura.ToString();
            lblTimeFechamento.Text = conteudo.DataHoraFechamento.ToString();
            lblUsuAbertura.Text = conteudo.UsuarioAbertura.Nome.ToString();
            txtNChamado.Text = conteudo.Manifestacao.NumeroChamado;
            txtNSerie.Text = conteudo.NSerie;
        }

        private void VerificarStatusFinalizado()
        {
            if (txtStatus.Text == "Finalizado")
            {
                if (!UsuarioLogado.IsEng())
                {
                    cboNovoStatus.Enabled = false;
                    cboNovoStatus.Text = "Status finalizado não pode ser alterado";
                }
                lblTimeFechamento.Visible = true;
                lblTitFechamento.Visible = true;
                lblTitIntervalo.Visible = true;
                lblDiasIntervalo.Visible = true;
                lblTitUsuFechamento.Visible = true;
                lblUsuFechamento.Text = conteudoAtual.UsuarioFechamento.Nome;
                lblUsuFechamento.Visible = true;
                CalculaIntervalo();
            }
        }

        private void DesabilitarEdicaoCampos()
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in gbxConteudo.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is TextBox)
                {
                    ((TextBox)ctrl).ReadOnly = true;
                }
            }

            txtNSerie.ReadOnly = false;
            txtEmpresaCliente.ReadOnly = true;
            txtStatus.ReadOnly = true;
        }

        private void cmdSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //VerificaAlteracaoDadosContato();
            VerificaAlteracaoStatus();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            this.Close();
        }

        private void VerificaAlteracaoStatus()
        {
            if (cboNovoStatus.Text == "Finalizado")
            {
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Confirma a alteração do status para 'Finalizado'? Após finalizado um registro não pode mais ser alterado.", "Importante!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    UpdateConteudo();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                    VerificarStatusFinalizado();
                    NotificaTermino();
                    MessageBox.Show("Registro atualizado com sucesso.");
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateConteudo();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateConteudo()
        {
            using (var context = new EFContext())
            {
                var newConteudo = context.Conteudos.Find(conteudoAtual.Id);
                if (cboNovoStatus.Text == "Finalizado")
                {
                    newConteudo.DataHoraFechamento = PegaDataHoraUsuario.DataHoraPadrao();
                    newConteudo.UsuarioFechamentoId = UsuarioLogado.Id;
                }
                if (cboNovoStatus.SelectedIndex > -1)
                {
                    newConteudo.Status = cboNovoStatus.Text;
                }
                newConteudo.Obs = txtObs.Text;
                newConteudo.Evidencias = txtEvidencias.Text;
                newConteudo.NSerie = txtNSerie.Text;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateDadosContato()
        {
            using (var context = new EFContext())
            {
                var newContato = context.Clientes.Find(conteudoAtual.Manifestacao.Cliente.Id);
                newContato.Email = txtEmailCliente.Text;
                newContato.Celular = mskCelularCliente.Text;
                newContato.Ramal = txtRamalCliente.Text;
                newContato.Telefone = mskTelefoneCliente.Text;
                newContato.Contato = txtContatoCliente.Text;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        private void NotificaTermino()
        {
            string procedimento = "fechamento";
            string dataHora = PegaDataHoraUsuario.DataHoraInvertida();

            string corpoEmailString = "<p><strong><font size='4'>Manifestação Finalizada</font></p>";
            corpoEmailString += "<p>Chamado: " + txtNChamado.Text + "</p>";
            corpoEmailString += "<p><strong><font size='3'>Empresa: " + txtEmpresaCliente.Text + "</font></p>";
            corpoEmailString += "<p><font size='2'> Conteúdo " + ": </font> </p>";
            corpoEmailString += "<p>Categoria: " + txtCategoria.Text + "</p>";
            corpoEmailString += "<p>Subcategoria: " + txtSubCategoria.Text + "</p>";
            corpoEmailString += "<p>Conteúdo: " + txtConteudo.Text + "</p>";
            corpoEmailString += "<br/>";
            corpoEmailString += "<p>Contato: " + txtContatoCliente.Text + "</p>";
            corpoEmailString += "<p>e-mail: " + txtEmailCliente.Text + "</p>";
            corpoEmailString += "<p>Telefone: " + mskTelefoneCliente.Text + "</p>";
            corpoEmailString += "<p>Ramal: " + txtRamalCliente.Text + "</p>";
            corpoEmailString += "<p>Celular: " + mskCelularCliente.Text + "</p>";
            corpoEmailString += "<p>Conteúdo encerrado por: " + nomeUsuario + "</p>";
            corpoEmailString += "<p>Data e hora do encerramento: " + lblTimeFechamento.Text + "</p>";
            corpoEmailString += "<p>Aberto em: " + lblTimeAbertura.Text + " por: " + lblUsuAbertura.Text + "</p>";
            corpoEmailString += "<p>Tempo decorrido até o fechamento: " + lblDiasIntervalo.Text + "</p>";

            List<string> vazio = new List<string>() { "", "" };

            string resultado = SendMail.EnviaMensagemEmail(StringsProjeto.remetente, "Manifestação Finalizada", corpoEmailString, procedimento, vazio);
        }    

        private void CalculaIntervalo()
        {
            DateTime fechamento = Convert.ToDateTime(lblTimeFechamento.Text.ToString());
            DateTime abertura = Convert.ToDateTime(lblTimeAbertura.Text.ToString());
            TimeSpan ts1 = fechamento.Subtract(abertura);
            string intervaloDias = ts1.ToString("dd");
            string intervaloHoras = ts1.ToString("hh");
            lblDiasIntervalo.Text = intervaloDias + " dias e " + intervaloHoras + " horas ";

        }

        private void txtEmailCliente_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textoEmailAlterado = true;
        }

        private void mskTelefoneCliente_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
        {
            textoTelefoneAlterado = true;
        }

        private void txtRamalCliente_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textoRamalAlterado = true;
        }

        private void mskCelularCliente_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
        {
            textoCelularAlterado = true;
        }

        private void txtContatoCliente_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textoContatoAlterado = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é código que gera este erro?

Comment: lblUsuFechamento.Text = conteudoAtual.UsuarioFechamento.Nome;

Comment: Ver só uma linha de código não me adianta nada

Comment: @LINQ, adicionei o código editando a pergunta (acima).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vamos lá, apesar da sua `DAL` está mascarando o problema, acredito que o método `GetConteudoByID(id)` está à fazer algo do genero.:

```
using (var context = new EFContext())
{
    return context.Conteudos.Find(id);
}
```

ao fazer isto, a conexão está sendo fechada quando o `Dispose()` do `context` é chamado, assim como o contexto do EF é destruído.

agora vamos analisar a seguinte linha.:

```
conteudoAtual.UsuarioFechamento.Nome
```

Como durante a consulta do conteúdo, você não realizou um `EagerLoad`, então o mesmo será consultado apenas quando for acessado, fazendo um `LazyLoad`, como o contexto já foi descartado, então à conexão não está mais disponível...

O que você pode fazer à curto prazo, é alterar o seu método `GetConteudoByID(id)` na `DAL` para.:

```
using (var context = new EFContext())
{
    return context.Conteudos
        .Include(u => u.UsuarioAbertura)
        .Include(u => u.UsuarioFechamento)
        .Include(u => u.Manifestacao)
        .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
}
```

A longo prazo, aconselho que abandone esta abordagem com `DAL`, você está apenas limitando artificialmente o `EF`, à longo prazo você verá que além de não trazer benefícios, será introduzido alguns problemas.

Se realmente quer reaproveitar o `GetConteudoByID(id)`, então faça uma extensao para o seu `EFContext`, e não tenha medo de acessar o `EFContext` direto no formulário.

```
public static class DAL_Conteudos
{
    public static Conteudo GetConteudoByID(this EFContext context, int id)
    {
        return context.Conteudos
            .Include(u => u.UsuarioAbertura)
            .Include(u => u.UsuarioFechamento)
            .Include(u => u.Manifestacao)
            .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
    }
}
```

acredite, não é feio fazer.:

```
public partial class FrmDetalhesConteudo : Form
{        
    EFContext context = new EFContext();
    Conteudo conteudoAtual = new Conteudo();

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            context?.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public FrmDetalhesConteudo(long idRow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        nomeUsuario = UsuarioLogado.Nome;
        conteudoAtual = context.GetConteudoByID(idRow);
        PreencheCampos(conteudoAtual);
        DesabilitarEdicaoCampos();
        VerificarStatusFinalizado();
        textoEmailAlterado = false;
        textoTelefoneAlterado = false;
        textoRamalAlterado = false;
        textoCelularAlterado = false;
        textoContatoAlterado = false;
    }

    private void VerificarStatusFinalizado()
    {
        if (txtStatus.Text == "Finalizado")
        {
            if (!UsuarioLogado.IsEng())
            {
                cboNovoStatus.Enabled = false;
                cboNovoStatus.Text = "Status finalizado não pode ser alterado";
            }
            lblTimeFechamento.Visible = true;
            lblTitFechamento.Visible = true;
            lblTitIntervalo.Visible = true;
            lblDiasIntervalo.Visible = true;
            lblTitUsuFechamento.Visible = true;
            lblUsuFechamento.Text = conteudoAtual.UsuarioFechamento.Nome;
            lblUsuFechamento.Visible = true;
            CalculaIntervalo();
        }
    }
}
```

Caso queira saber mais á repeito sobre `Por que não é legal usar DAL/Repository com EF`.:

[Quando usar Entity Framework com Repository Pattern?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern)

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!