# Lazy Loading EF Core, carregar entidades filhas e subfilhas?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Tenho uma `Web Api` que estou desenvolvendo utilizando o `DotNet Core` e `EF Cor` porém está com o `Lazy Loading` ativo, só que em alguns casos preciso carregar as entidades **filhas** e **filhas das filhas**, criei um repositório genérico para efetuar o `CRUD` no banco, consigo carregar as **filhas**, mas as **filhas das filhas** não consigo.

A função Get genérica que carrega as filhas.

```
public IQueryable<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params string[] include) 
     where T : class
{
        IQueryable<T> result = this._context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);

        foreach (string item in include)
        {
            result = result.Include(item).AsQueryable();
        }

        return result.AsQueryable();
}
```

Utilizando essa função seria

```
var entidade this.repository.Get<Entity>(x => x.Id == 1, "Filha1", "Filha2")
                 .FirstOrDefault();

entidade.Filha1 // Carrega Corretamente
entidade.Filha2 // Carrega Corretamente
entidade.Filha1.SubFilha1 // Quero conseguir carregar esse nível da entidade
```

Implementação do Repositório Genérico:

```
using API.Model.Context;
using API.Model.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace API.Model.Repositories
{
    public class Repository : IDisposable, IRepository
    {
        private readonly ApiContext _context;

        public Repository(ApiContext context)
        {
            this._context = context;
        }

        public void Add<T>(T obj) where T : class
        {
            this._context.Set<T>().Add(obj);
        }

        public void Delete<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
        {
            this._context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToList()
                .ForEach(del => this._context.Set<T>().Remove(del));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this._context.Dispose();
        }

        public void Edit<T>(T obj) where T : class
        {
            this._context.Entry<T>(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public int ExecuteSql(string psSql, params object[] poParams)
        {
            return _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(psSql, poParams);
        }

        public T Find<T>(params object[] key) where T : class
        {
            return this._context.Set<T>().Find(key);
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) 
               where T : class
        {
            return this._context.Set<T>().Where(predicate)
                       .AsQueryable();
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate,
                                    params string[] include)
             where T : class
        {
            IQueryable<T> result = this._context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);

            foreach (string item in include)
            {

                result = result.Include(item).AsQueryable();
            }

            return result.AsQueryable();
        }

        public IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class
        {
            return this._context.Set<T>();
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            this._context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Entidade Pai

```
    [Table("Booking")]
    public class Booking
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<RoomStay> RoomStay { get; set; }
    }
```

Entidade Filha

```
    [Table("RoomStay")]
    public class RoomStay
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BookingId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BookingId")]
        public virtual Booking Booking { get; set; }

        public int? RoomTypeId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RoomTypeId")]
        public virtual RoomType RoomType { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<RoomStayGuest> RoomStayGuest { get; set;                 }
        public virtual ICollection<RoomStayFnrh> RoomStayFnrh { get; set; }
    }
```

Preciso carregar as entidades RoomType e as coleções RoomStayGuest e RoomStayFnrh

Comment: Esse é o grande problema de fazer um repositório junto ao Entity Framework. Perceba que você possui um `.Where()` simples junto com um `.include()`, que se tornou algo complexo devido ao seu repositório. Mais sobre: [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern)

Comment: já tentou usar sua logica no seu loop para carregar o próximo nível ? ou seja após você fazer o  result = result.Include(item).AsQueryable(); e obter o entidade.Filha1 fazer novamento o loop para incluir o próximo nivel.

Comment: @GabrielColetta bem interessante o posicionamento sobre os repositórios nesse link

Comment: @LucasRiechelmannRamos qual das resposta você utilizou para solução do seu problema?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic a sua resposta, foi a melhor para a minha situação, obrigado

Comment: @LucasRiechelmannRamos porque eu estou perguntando, porque a resposta com aceitação está com problemas ... foi isso minha preocupação.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para incluir vários níveis de dados relacionados, utilize o método `ThenInclude()`.

## Exemplos

<sub>**Entity Framework** - Dados Relacionados</sub>

```
var example = context.Parent
                            .Include(x => x.Child)
                            .ThenInclude(g => g.Grandson)
```

<sub>**Entity Framework** - Encadeamento de dados relacionados</sub>

```
var example = context.Parent
                            .Include(x => x.Child)
                            .ThenInclude(g => g.Grandson)
                            .ThenInclude(gg => gg.GreatGrandson)
```

<sub>**Método genérico**</sub>

```
public IQueryable<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>> include = null) 
     where T : class
{
        IQueryable<T> result = this._context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);

        if (include != null)
           result = include(result);

        return result.AsQueryable();
}
```

<sub>**Utilização do método genérico**</sub>

```
var example = this.repository.Get<Entity>(
                                           x => x.Id == 1, 
                                           r => r
                                                     .Include(c => c.Child)
                                                     .ThenInclude(g => g.Grandson))
                                                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Para mais informações de carregamento de dados relacionados, acesse: [Carregamento de Dados Relacionados](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Comment: Desse modo eu teria que implementar um repositório para cada entidade, estou procurando uma forma genérica para utilizar o repositório genérico, se não conseguir achar um modo vou ter que utilizar esse mesmo, mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Realmente. Já pensou em utilizar o parâmetro "include" como um IIncludableQueryable? Desta forma seria possível realizar utilizando um repositório genérico.

Comment: Está certinho, só não utilize `ref` é uma palavra reservada!

Comment: Realmente, não havia percebido. Obrigado.

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates se fez o teste com esse método génerico, comigo isso ai não rolou não?

Comment: Fiz a correção.

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates achei interessante a implementação mas está dando erro na linha "result = include(result);" o include não permite usar como um método, to vendo aqui o que pode ser.

Comment: Você inseriu  a atualização que eu fiz?

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates funcionou faltava atualizar o método obrigado

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates eu fiz o teste com esse código porque eu vi agora, e achei muito estranho a nomenclatura exigida pelo Include não é essa, por acaso funcionou com você? fiz alguns teste por desencargo e não funciona... !!!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic É a mesma nomenclatura. Talvez, para um código mais elegante seja necessário criar um Extension Method. Funciona, pode testar.

Comment: Já testei e não funciona. Porque ó método Include exige outro tipo de código.

Comment: O método Include utilizado na resposta é uma extensão localizada na classe EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions e necessita apenas que o tipo que será estendido seja IQueryable<TEntity>. O trecho de código na resposta funciona. Caso tenha dúvidas, por favor, abra uma pergunta.

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates seguinte eu não tenho duvidas nenhuma ... só estou tentando ajudar, mas, tudo bem sem problemas ...

Answer (score 2):

É só você colocar as relações separadas por um ponto (`.`), exemplo:

```
var entidade this.repository.Get<Entity>(x => x.Id == 1, "Filha1.SubFilha1")
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

não vai precisar nem mudar o código do `repository` é só passar dessa forma o nome das relações `Filha1.SubFilha1` e assim por diante.

O código [Include e ThenInclude](http://Carregamento%20de%20dados%20relacionados) seria o ideal, mas, você teria que mudar o código do seu `repository` para que o mesmo possa suportar esses métodos com alguma lógica diferente da atual.

Fui questionado pelo @GabrielColleta se isso funciona, na versão `Entity Framework Core` e é até um ponto interessante a dizer, sim isso funciona perfeitamente e está contido na versão mais atual que é uma das coisas trazidas da versão anterior, esse método `Include` com paramento Texto (`string`) resolve as relações das relações, e acredito ser útil para resolver esse problema. Esse `Include` com paramento Texto (`string`) não tem o `ThenInclude` como é utilizado no outro que é uma Expressão `Lambda`.

> Preciso carregar as entidades RoomType e as coleções RoomStayGuest e RoomStayFnrh

```
var entidade this.repository
          .Get<Entity>(x => x.Id == 1, 
                       "RoomStay.RoomType", 
                       "RoomStay.RoomStayGuest",
                       "RoomStay.RoomStayFnrh")
          .FirstOrDefault();
```

Testes realizados com `Entity Framework Core 2.0.1`

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [Carregamento de dados relacionados](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/querying/related-data)
- [Reading related data - EF Core with ASP.NET Core MVC tutorial (6 of 10)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data)
- [When to use Include() with Entity Framework?](http://foreverframe.net/when-use-include-with-entity-framework/)

Comment: Carregar vários níveis funciona no Entity Framework Core `.Include("Filha1.SubFilha1")`? Não encontrei nada do gênero.

Comment: @GabrielColetta sim carrega, eu estudo a muito tempo e essa funcionalidade vem da versão anterior e continua, inclusive antes de postar essa resposta fiz o teste ... funcionou e gerou a `SQL` com os `Inner Join` com todas as relações que foram pedidas!!!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic isso foi a primeira coisa que tinha testado antes de pesquisar outro modo de fazer, mas está dando o Nome do Objeto é inválido, vou efetuar alguns testes para ver se não estou errando na hierarquia, mas obrigado pela dica

Comment: @LucasRiechelmannRamos coloca na sua pergunta as 3 classes que eu te falo aonde está errando!

Comment: Qual a versão do Entity Framework Core?

Comment: @GabrielColetta 2.0.1 a que eu fiz essa resposta.

Comment: @GabrielColetta 2.0.1

Comment: @VirgilioNovic atualizei a resposta com as entidades

Comment: @LucasRiechelmannRamos eu fiz todos os testes possiveis e funciona perfeitamente, e adicionei a resposta para o seu problema! dê uma olhada

Comment: @VirgilioNovic para a entidade RoomType funcionou para as outras duas não, acredito que para ICollections deva ser de outro modo.

Comment: Não é desse jeito mesmo @LucasRiechelmannRamos .... eu fiz os teste como disse, para agregação e coleção... funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: @LucasRiechelmannRamos dá uma olhada nos seus relacionamentos !!! talvez também seja isso ... e coloque na pergunta como você fez!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic ok vou verificar aqui e atualizo a pergunta quando resolver

Comment: resolvido muito obrigado, faltava adicionar o Migrations e atualizar a base de dados