# Não consigo usar o método Find() utilizando EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou usando o [seguinte tutorial](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3347/trabalhando-com-repositorio-generico-no-entity-framework.aspx) para utilizar o Repository Pattern:

Segue minha classe repositório

```
public class Repository<T> : IDisposable, IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly EntityContext ctx;

    public Repository(EntityContext _ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = _ctx;
    }

    public T getByID(object id)
    {
        return ctx.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }
}
```

Porém na hora da criação do método `GetByID(int id)`, está estourando o erro abaixo.

> DbSet does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no extension method 'Find' accepting a first argument of type '`DbSet<T>`' could be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)

No tutorial que estou seguindo, o instrutor ensina da mesma forma que mostrei aqui.

Comment: Está usando `using System.Collections.Generic` ?

Comment: Aham, estou sim.
 `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: `using System.Linq`

Comment: Qual a versão do .NET? Qual a versão do Entity Framework?

Comment: Experimentar trocar o EntityContext por DbContext

Comment: Isso é EntityFramework Core? De onde surgiu esta classe EntityContext?

Comment: @bunomonteiro a versão do .NET é **.NET Framework 4.7.1** e a versão do Entity Framework que usei na hora da instalação via NuGet, foi a seguinte: **-Version 7.0.0-rc1-final -Pre**

Comment: @LINQ Não é o o Core... E a [classe EntityContext](https://ghostbin.com/paste/kduwd) é o contexto da apicação, onde nela tenho declarado as classes que irão ser refletida como um banco de dados.

Comment: @RenanNarciso Por favor, adicione os trechos relevantes na sua pergunta e não em fontes externas. Minha rede é bloqueada aqui.

Comment: @bunomonteiro, troquei EntityContext por DbContext e mesmo assim eu não consigo chamar o método Find()

Comment: cara, acho que é pq o find precisa de uma expressão lambda, então teria que ser tipo `Find(x => x.valor == id)`

Comment: Instala a -Version 6.2.0 que é a estável.

Comment: @GustavoForteAndreli eu sei que precisa de uma expressão lambda. O problema é que não estou conseguindo utilizá-lo

Comment: Já tentou mudar o método `public T getByID<T>(object id)`?

Comment: Olá @VirgilioNovic o problema ja foi solucionado

Comment: Tem como colocar a solução.

Comment: Coloquei sim, obrigado pela informação.

Fiz uma resposta lá no final do tópico e coloquei como **Solução**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido, instalei o EntityFramework 6.2.0 e consegui.

Answer (score 0):

Instalei o EntityFramework 6.2.0 como o [@BrunoMonteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/20329/bunomonteiro) comentou e solucionei o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!

Verifique se o contexto que está sendo passado para o repositório, está correto.
Eu já usei este formato, e o que você está apresentando deveria funcionar. 
Aparentemente você tem um problema na instancia do seu contexto.

Mas por regra eu não gosto de usar o Find, pois ele tem dois problemas.

1) Se você estiver usando Lazy Loading, e seu objeto tiver muitos subobjetos ou listas de relacinamento do EF, caso você navegue por elas, o EF fará varias idas ao seu banco de dados, o que é uma falha de desempenho de sua aplicação.

2) Se você não tiver usando Lazy Loading, caso precise desses dados dos subobjetos, não conseguirá acesso a eles.

O Ideal seria você usar

```
context.Set<TEntity>().Include().Where()
```

Os Includes é para acessar os subobjetos, porem a metodologia de repositório não é a mais adequada para isso.

Implementar Repositório para EF não é aconselhável.

Esse site tem uma documentação bem completa sobre o EF. Sugiro que leia atentamente para que você crie uma infraestrutura adequada a sua necessidade.

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/querying-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: hmmm, interessante. Mas tipo a ideia que quero de usar o Repositório genérico é para que eu não crie vários DAOs entendeu?
Quero que um repositório sirva para todas as classes de negócio.
-
E por que não É aconselhável usar Repositório para EF?

Comment: Entendi, porem o EF foi criado para extinguir a necessidade de um repositório, você pode criar microservices para cada ação do crud, e utilizá-los em seu momentos oportunos. EX: para adicionar você criaria uma classe chamada Adder, e no controller você instanciaria Adder. Adder pode ser genérico assim como o repositório mas com apenas uma responsabilidade. A meu ver o Padrão Repositório fere o principio da Responsabilidade Unica. Sem contar que no padrão repositório fica impossível você fazer aquelas considerações sobre o getter.

Comment: @RenanNarciso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern